# template member functions in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with generics in c++.I have two Matrix.h and Matrix.cpp files.Here is files:

```
#pragma once
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        static T** addSub(int size,T** firstMatrix,T** secondMatrix,int operation);
}
```

and Matrix.cpp

```
#include "Martix.h"
template<class T>
static T** Matrix<T>::addSub( int n,T **firstMatrix,T **secondMatrix,int operation)
{
    //variable for saving result operation
    T **result = new T*[n];

    //create result matrix
    for( int i=0;i<n;i++)
        result[i] = new T[n];

    //calculate result
    for( int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            result[i][j] = 
            (operation == 1) ? firstMatrix[i][j] + secondMatrix[i][j]:
                                firstMatrix[i][j] - secondMatrix[i][j];

    return result;
}
```

when I run these I get the below error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int * * __cdecl Matrix<int>::addSub(int,int * *,int * *,int)" (?addSub@?$Matrix@H@@SAPAPAHHPAPAH0H@Z) referenced in function "public: static int * * __cdecl Matrix<int>::strassenMultiply(int,int * *,int * *)" (?strassenMultiply@?$Matrix@H@@SAPAPAHHPAPAH0@Z) C:\Users\ba.mehrabi\Desktop\Matrix\matrixMultiplication\main.obj    matrixMultiplication
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have template method definition in the same compilation unit as declaration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488959/how-do-you-create-a-static-template-member-function-that-performs-actions-on-a-te

Comment: You misspelt the name of the include file. I wonder if you're giving us your real code here, or if you're just writing down some fiction from memory... Also, C++ doesn't have "generics"; if you come from a Java background, it'd probably be worth your while to accustom yourself with the common C++ idioms, which are quite different. For example, you should rarely or never say `new` in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't have the declaration of a template class in the *.cpp files.  The full definition has to stay in the header file.  This is a rule of many C++ compilers.

See this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

> 1. A template is not a class or a function. A template is a "pattern"
>      that the compiler uses to generate a family of classes or functions.
> 2. In order for the compiler to generate the code, it must see both
>      the template definition (not just declaration) and the specific
>      types/whatever used to "fill in" the template. For example, if you're
>      trying to use a Foo, the compiler must see both the Foo template
>      and the fact that you're trying to make a specific Foo.
> 3. Your compiler probably doesn't remember the details of one .cpp
>      file while it is compiling another .cpp file. It could, but most do
>      not and if you are reading this FAQ, it almost definitely does not.
>      BTW this is called the "separate compilation model."

The link has a workaround, but keep in mind that a template is a glorified macro so the header file is probably the best place for it.

The poster of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) SO post shows a demonstration of the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the definition of functions of a class template, should go in the header itself.

Second, if you define the `static` member function out of class (though in the header itself), then don't use the `static` keyword (in the definition). It only needed in the declaration only.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
template Matrix<int>;
```

at the end of your cpp file and it will work. But you need to learn a few things about templates, otherwise you'll have to deal with lots of issues you don't understand.