# Linking templates with g++

Tags: c++, templates, linker, g++

I'm implementing a hash table and linked list in C++ (no STL - don't ask) using templates, and I'm running into problems linking them with g++. If I #include all my .cpp files together, everything works, so my code definitely works, it's just the linking that's tripping me up.

I read [the bit in the GCC manual about template instantiation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template-Instantiation), but wasn't sure how to apply it.

My problem:
I have a `HashMap<T>` and `HashEntry<T>` for my hash table (`<T>` is the value - my keys are `std::string`s). My linked list has `LinkedList<T>` and `Node<T>` (where `<T>` is the value).

In my hash map, I have:

```
template <class T> class HashMap {
    ...
    private:
        LinkedList< HashEntry<T> >** buckets;
 }
```

Which gives me a linked list of `HashEntry<T>`s.

In a separate file, I have my Linked List class declaration:

```
template <class T>
    class Node {
        ...
        private:
             T data;
}

template <class T> class LinkedList {
     ...
     private:
     Node<T> * first;
}
```

Then, when I try to link everything (after compiling with `g++ -c -frepo *.cpp`), I get:

```
g++ -frepo -o app LinkedList.o HashMap.o
[...unrelated errors about not having a main method - they go away when I link that in]
HashMap.o: In function `HashMap<int>::~HashMap()':
HashMap.cpp:(.text._ZN7HashMapIiED1Ev[HashMap<int>::~HashMap()]+0x65): undefined reference to `LinkedList<HashEntry<int> >::~LinkedList()'
HashMap.o: In function `HashMap<int>::insert(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)':
HashMap.cpp:(.text._ZN7HashMapIiE6insertESsi[HashMap<int>::insert(std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)]+0xff): undefined reference to     `Node<HashEntry<int> >::setData(HashEntry<int>)'
```

Googling around, I've seen suggestions for declaring the explicit template types that my program uses. This works for the `HashMap` and `HashEntry` (I added (`template class HashMap< int >` and `template class HashEntry< int >`.

However, I can't figure out how to make this work for `LinkedList` and `Node` classes, since the template instances are of `HashEntries<int>`. BUT, I can't put that into the `LinkedList.h` file, since it's `#include`d by my Hash tables. I also couldn't get an advanced/extern declaration working for it.

I'm sure there's something fairly simple that I'm missing to make all this work. Any tips?

Comment: Is there a definition of your `LinkedList` destructor anywhere?  Or `Node<...>::setData()`?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but is there any reason you're not using something like make, waf, SCons, etc.?

Comment: @kotlinski: Correct, my HashMap uses the LinkedList (for chaining), and I've got a `#include "LinkedList.h"` at the top of my file.

Comment: @robert: I've got my ~LinkedList() and setData in the .cpp file (`template <class T> LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()`). Again, it compiles if I #include all my .cpp files together.

No build system - just trying to get it working from scratch for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making template classes, it is not a good idea to put them in .cpp files and compile separately. The right way is to put them in .h files (both declaration and definition) and include them where you need them.

The reason is that templates won't actually be compiled unless their template arguments are defined.

(Intentionally avoiding mentioning the `export` keyword.)

Comment: You know, there's that `export` thingy getting removed in C++0x... oh right :P +1

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'll make that work. For now I'm just #including my .cpp file into the .h file. Is that an alright thing to do, or should I really move the code inside my class declaration?

Comment: @Taj Morton move it inside the class declaration. Including a cpp file is generally considered bad form.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're defining template class members in LinkedList.cpp.  Templates generally need to be completely defined (not just declared) in the .h file.  For ways around this, see [storing C++ template functions in a .cpp file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)  But I would avoid it--it causes more problems than it's worth.