# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, templates, g++, hashtable

I'm new to C++, and I just can't seem to figure out what's causing these errors.

The following is my header file:

```
#ifndef TABLE
#define TABLE

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

typedef struct {
    double successful , unsuccessful[2] ;
} Perform ;

using namespace std ;

template <class DATA>
class Table {

private :
    vector<DATA>* slot;
    vector<bool>* passBits;
    vector<bool>* full;
    int tableSize;

public :
    explicit Table ( unsigned size = 5 ) ;
    ~Table( ) ; //destructor
    void empty ( ) ;
    bool insert ( DATA & data ) ;
    bool insertD ( DATA & data ) ;
    bool fetch ( DATA & data ) const ;
    void print ( ostream & ) const ;
    Perform perform ( ) const ;
} ;

template <class DATA>
ostream & operator << ( ostream & out , const Table<DATA> & table )
{
    table.print( out ) ;   return out ;
}

#include "table.cpp"

#endif
```

My table.cpp is as follows:

```
template <class DATA>
Table<DATA> :: Table ( unsigned size ) // Error
{

}

template <class DATA>
Table<DATA> :: ~Table( ) // Error
{

}

template <class DATA>
void Table<DATA> :: empty ( ) // Error
{

}

template <class DATA>
bool Table<DATA> :: insertD ( DATA & data ) // Error
{

}

#include "MyData.hpp"
```

The first two lines marked `// Error` have the error. The last two have an "expected initializer before ‘<’ token" error.

This is the outline that was given to me. I am not allowed to modify the table.hpp file except for the private fields.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Who or what book is teaching the awful practice of #include with .cpp files?

Comment: Why do you include your `.cpp` file from the header file? That's unusual. Normally, it's the other way around (`.cpp` files including header files).

Comment: This is the "outline" I was given.

Answer (score 2):

You're compiling a .cpp file that isn't.  Put the definitions of your class template's constructors, methods, etc. directly into the class definition, and delete your .cpp file.

For example, compare with this code which is what the compiler sees and [shows your first error](http://codepad.org/Ds9DnmSM):

```
template<class DATA>
Table<DATA>::Table(unsigned size) {}
```

Notice this code does not define the Table class template before trying to define this ctor, so the compiler is confused about what able is supposed to be in the first place.

---

You can work around your braindead instructions which prevent fixing the code correctly.  First, never compile table.cpp and don't let tools assume they can compile or process it as an implementation file (which many rightly assume).  Secondly, include your header (table.hpp?) at the top of table.cpp, since it is unlikely you will catch every occurrence of tools using .cpp as a valid implementation file.

Comment: The problem is I am not allowed to modify anything besides my table.cpp file. The only parts of table.hpp that I am allowed to change are the private fields

Comment: @John: That is hugely unfortunate. Perhaps this is the only serious problem with your class, lecture, or whatever, but if there are many more, you can at least get a [good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) for yourself.  You should update the question with this restriction.

Comment: @John so why not put `#include "table.hpp"` in that .cpp file's top.

Comment: +1, except the last sentence.  `table.hpp` is an "inline header file" that contains definitions for all inline functions.  It is indirectly included by the clients.  I've seen this as `table.inlines.hpp` to avoid confusion with source files.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Do you mean "table.cpp is an ..."?  I don't see how you know how John is using table.hpp, but I did try to stress the point that table.cpp should not be named with ".cpp".  Because table.cpp depends on the header and is being used independently (i.e. compiled), it should include the header; what is the problem with the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by putting the definition of the template into the head file. C++ does not support seperating the declaration and definition of a template in different files.
See this
[Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

However some compilers such as IBM xlc and HP acc can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you supplied (except for the unsual include of a .cpp file but that's legal).

Therefor I think you're trying to compile `table.cpp`. If so ,then that is an mistake on your part since it is compile through the `include` statement in your header-file.

You only need to compile the file in which you use the template.

EDIT: when used right with `#include "table.h"` in a `test.cpp` it compiled fine. When I tried to compile `table.cpp` (on MSVS 2010) In got 'missing ; before < '

Comment: John isn't going to compile `table.cpp`, it's an "inline header file".  I've often seen this as `table.inlines.hpp`.

Comment: @André Caron: How do you know that he's not trying tompile table.cpp ? Are you sitting beside him ? And I am aware that he's using it as an include file. And "inline header file" is a riduculous term.

Comment: @AndréCaron: It's most likely his tools are compiling it automatically – e.g. after it has been "added to the project" – since it is named ".cpp".