# Template class compilation "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token" error

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having trouble with compiling my template class. This is my list.cpp

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
    length = 0;
}

template <class T>
List<T>::~List()
{

}


template <class T>
List<T> & List<T>::operator=(const List<T> & rhs)
{
    List<T> hha;
    return hha;
}


template <class T>
int List<T>::size()
{
    return length;
}
```

ANd this is my list.h

```
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_

#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class List
{
    private:

        class ListNode
        {
            public:
                ListNode();
                ListNode(const T element);

                ListNode *next;
                T data;
        };

    public:

        // big3
        List();
        ~List();
        List<T> & operator=(const List<T> & rhs);

        int size();
        bool empty();
        void print(ostream & os) const;


    private:
        ListNode * head;
        ListNode * tail;
        int length;
};

#include "list.cpp"

#endif
```

when I run g++ list.cpp

I get errors

expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token

for definitions of constructor, destructor, and operator...

I don't know what seems to be wrong

Comment: On which of the many `<` do you get that error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916506/expected-constructor-destructor-or-type-conversion-before-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template implementation goes in the header.

It is a bit of a hack but it is how it is done.

Comment: That "a bit of" part made me a day :D

Comment: I don' know where my bit on the use std::list in preference to your own implementation has gone, but you should probably take that advice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you currently encounter is that you `list.cpp` doesn't include you `list.h`: the compiler sees a couple of definitions for things which aren't declared, yet. You can fix this problem by including `list.h` at the top of your file:

```
#include "list.h"
...
```

However, this will essentially lead to a problem coming: if you actually want to use your `List<T>` with some type, the compiler will need to see the template definition where the class template is used. That is, typically you will implement your templates in the header file. The alterntaive is to implement templates in an implementation file and explicitly instantiating the types it is to be used with. This is quite reasonable for some templates but for something intended to be used for an unknown number of types this isn't practical.

BTW, you are using names which you are not allowed to touch: names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the C++ implementation, i.e. the compiler and the standard library. Names using two consecutive underscores anywhere are also reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Since `list.hpp` doesn't get `#include`d in `list.cpp`, the compiler doesn't know about the template definition in that header when you try to compile `list.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

You compile `list.cpp`, that defines your list member functions. But it doesn't contain the template class declaration - that is in the header.

I see you include cpp in your list header. This will sort of work if you include the list header in some other cpp file and make sure `list.cpp` will not be compiled as a separate compilation unit.

What I mean is i.e. file main.cpp:

```
#include "list.h"
int main()
{}
```

Then compile this with `g++ main.cpp`.

Usually you just want to avoid cpp files when using templates altogether. Just stuff everything in the header and include that. Or alternatively I would at least rename your `list.cpp` to `list.impl` or some other name. This way one might be less tempted to actually try to compile that file directly.

Comment: I just compiled main.cpp without changing any of the code above and it worked lol. Thank you!

Comment: @wayfare Glad I could help :) btw. it is customary on SO to accept the answer, if it helped you with your question (or accept the most helpful answer). This goes also for your other question.