# Building "Monolithic" Libraries

Tags: c++, libraries, compilation, building

I have a series of small library "modules" designed to handle very specific tasks.  A single module usually consists of just a `.h` and a `.cpp`, and possibly another set to provide relevant non-friend, non-member functions that the user might find useful.

For example, `Foo.h` might declare a class called `Foo`, that `Foo.cpp` defines, and  `FooUtilities.h` might declare a function that uses `Foo` which is defined by `FooUtilities.cpp`.

Normally to use these modules in my programs, I add the `.h` and `.cpp` to my project and `#include` the `.h` in whatever files need it.  However, for larger programs that use more potentially-interdependent modules, this is growing to be a big inconvenience.  Therefore, I'd like to compile it all as a single monolithic static or dynamic library so I can just add the library file to my project, set the header search directories to folders that contain the aforementioned `.h` files, and compile.

Seems pretty simple, right?  All I'd have to do is start a new project with a static/dynamic library as its build target and then add all the appropriate files.  The `.cpp` files, which `#include` the `.h` files anyway, will be compiled and added to the final product.

However, some of the modules use templates and therefore have to use `.tpp` instead of `.cpp`.  The `.tpp` files are only meant for organization and are `#include`d by their respective header files, which is the opposite of how the normal modules are handled.  Because of this, *just adding them to my library project won't compile anything.*

How can I work around this?  Should I have a `CompileThis.cpp` file that includes all the modules that use templates?  If so, should this file also include the non-template modules?  It seems like this could rapidly become an organizational mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many compilers cannot "precompile" templates into libraries.  My best suggestion is to treat them like header files; header files are not compiled into libraries, they are just included.

I compile code into a library when the amount of changes is minimal.  This often speeds up the build process since those files don't need to be compiled again (and again...).

Comment: So there's no way to use template code unless it's included through literal text substitution, i.e. the `#include` directive?  I'd like to hide my code as well, if that's possible.

Comment: @Maxpm In current C++ there is no way to hide your template code.

Comment: The current C++ standard does provide a way to hide your template code, namely through the `export` keyword.  However, most compilers do not implement it (only those that use an EDG front end do - I think).  Furthermore that keyword will be deprecated in C++0x.  Using it is not recommended.  Further details are available in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416872/using-export-keyword-with-templates

Answer (score 1):

> Should I have a CompileThis.cpp file that includes all the modules that use templates?

Yes - you'll still need an object to link. It's also nice because it will perform the syntax/instantiation checks (assuming your depends are properly ordered).

> If so, should this file also include the non-template modules?

that depends on the structure.

- at minimum, it should include/define what it must export (and their dependencies).
- it should often include the headers represented by the module, in order to easily detect errors issues at the package level.
- ideally, you'll add all necessary concepts and some instantiations (in some cases).

this makes it easier to maintain, and will not require major restructuring when you realize you have moved from needing 0 exported symbols to needing one or more.