# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, templates

I'm fairly new to C++ but already gained some experience in java.

In following short c++-exercise I tried to build  a stack by using a class template.
Unfortunately it fails to compile and I can't figure out why.

The error message is:

> Stack.cpp:6: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before `‘<’` token
>   Stack.cpp:14: error: expected initializer before `‘<’` token
>   Stack.cpp:25: error: expected initializer before `‘<’` token
>   make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Stack.o] Error 1

Here's the Stack.h:

```
template <class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack(int = 10);

    ~Stack() {
        delete [] stackPtr;
    }

    int isEmpty()const {
        return top == -1;
    }

    int isFull() const {
        return top == size - 1;
    }

    int push(const T&);
    int pop(T&);

private:
    int size; // length i.e. number of elements on Stack.
    int top; //index of top element
    T* stackPtr;
};
```

Stack.cpp:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int s) {
    size = s > 0 && s < 1000 ? s : 15;
    top = -1; // initialize stack
    stackPtr = new T[size];
}

template <class T>
int Stack<T>::push(const T& item) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        stackPtr[++top] = item;
        return 1; // push successful
    }
    return 0; // push unsuccessful
}

template <class T>
int Stack<T>::pop(T& popValue) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        popValue = stackPtr[top--];
        return 1; // pop successful
    }
    return 0; // pop unsuccessful
}
```

The main.cpp looks like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Stack<int> intStack;
    int i = 1.1;
    cout << "Pushing:" << endl;
    while (intStack.push(i)) {
        cout << i << ' ';
        i += 1;
    }
    cout << endl << "Stack Full" << endl
         << endl << "Popping elements from is" << endl;
    while (intStack.pop(i))
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl << "Stack Empty" << endl;
}
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: int = 10, I can already tell you that's an issue. In stack.h

Comment: And note that `int i = 1.1` will become `1`.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) question, on why you can't have templates in `.cpp` files.

Comment: @Laika: @Xeo pointed out the fundamental problem, you should have declaration and definition of template in same header file & also there are other errors as @netrom and @ Lainlwakura pointed out.

Comment: I would also suggest reading about constructors and more specifically initialization lists! The usage of them is very important, see for example [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6). Also, when a method returns only two values (success/failure), it would be more idiomatic and less-confusing to return booleans instead of ints.

Comment: @Lainlwakura: Why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: ok, I have changed 'int = 10' to 'int size = 10', but that doesn't solve the issue. Are all definitions supposed to be in the .h-file?

Comment: @Laika: The answer to your immediate compile error is that you need to `#include "Stack.h"` at the top of `Stack.cpp` but the issues remain that a definition of the _members_ of the `Stack` template need to be visible where you instantiate `Stack<int>` in `main`.

Comment: @Laika: Yes, see the links I gave for explanations. As long as you plan to use the template in multiple translation units, they need to be header-only.

Comment: @Laika: Lainlwakura was mistaken. There's nothing wrong with `int = 10`.

Answer (score 3):

I copy-pasted your code as-is in Visual Studio 2010 and compiled and linked without any problems, so long the content from both header and cpp are in one place (i.e., pasted both in main.cpp). Likewise, [GCC doesn't complain either](http://ideone.com/wy4gA).

After splitting it up in a header and a cpp, it still compiled just fine, but now there were linker errors, the reason of them being explained in the links I gave in my comment ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file), [this C++ FAQ links might also be interesting](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12)). Syntactically, there is nothing wrong with your code as far as I and my compiler can see.

The only thing I could imagine, seeing that you first linked to pastebin where you head the complete files pasted (which I edited in the question then), was that you never included `Stack.h` in `Stack.cpp` (I think this might be the reason, as your `Stack.h` paste even had the include guards). Still, the fundamental problem remains.

Comment: You're right, the include-statement was missing in my previous posting. However, it exists in my cpp-file!

Comment: @Laika: Interesting. What happens if you just copy-paste the cpp content into the header right after the class definition?

Comment: What is the header file supposed to look then?

Comment: @Laika: Excluding the include guards, something like [this](http://ideone.com/N5ezv)

Comment: When I change my header file to this, there are some symbols which cannot be found:

Stack.h: In member function ‘int Stack<T>::push(const T&)’:
In file included from main.cpp:3:
Stack.h:28: error: ‘item’ was not declared in this scope
Stack.h: In member function ‘int Stack<T>::pop(T&)’:
Stack.h:36: error: ‘popValue’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o] Error 1

Comment: @Laika: Yeah, i said *something* like this. :P I missed the parameter names for the push and pop function, but you could've seeb that yourself, y'know.