# I have a template function defined for a certain class in a cpp - not hpp. Can it be used by a child class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I used the following to write my template inside a cpp instead of the header file because i prefer to keep the code clean.

[Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

In **.hpp**
`template <class obj_class> void plotLaser(int zoom, void * obj);`

In **.cpp**
`class visualizer {...};`
`class annotator : public visualizer {...};`
`template void plotLaser<visualizer>(int zoom, void * obj) {...};`

Can I use the template to call `plotLaser<annotator>(...);` or do I have to rewrite it?

Comment: No I'm in the process of splitting my class right now to be honest, I can't afford to mess things more. I will try it later though, probably with dummy classes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to re-write it I think.
Because your code

```
    template void plotLaser<visualizer>(int zoom, void * obj) {...};
```

is a specialization.

if you need one for annotator, you need to one specialization for it.