# Separate .h and .cpp files in template class implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a template class that can form classes depending on the `<class>` I pass. The problem is I cannot declare and define in the same `.h` file. In my project, the UTF tool can only work with the `.cpp` files (for code coverage, etc.). I have seen in a blog that they say “Add `.cpp` instead of `.h`”. Is this advisable?

`Template.h`

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H_
#define TEMPLATE_H_

template<class T>
class Template
{
public:
    T Add(T a,T b);
};

#endif /* TEMPLATE_H_ */
```

`Template.cpp`

```
#include "Template.h"

template<class T>
T Template<T>::Add(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

`Main.cpp`

```
#include "Template.cpp" //Is this a good practise? 
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Template<int> obj;
    std::cout<<obj.Add(3,4)<<std::endl;
}
```

If this is not advisable then how do I solve this issue? `export`?

Comment: Another canonical Q&A: [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115703)

Answer (score 10):

Compiler needs to have an access to the implementation of the methods in order to instantiate the template class, thus the most common practice is either to ***include the definitions of a template in the header file that declares that template*** or to ***define them in header files***.

See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1168156)

Answer (score 5):

Templates must be defined in every translation unit in which they are used. This means they must be defined in header files. If your tool insists on the extension `.cpp`, you can as well provide it, just like you did.

You don't even need to split the pseudo-header into `.h` and `.cpp` in this case. You can just put it all in the `.cpp` and `#include` that.

Comment: This is not strictly true. Although it is most convenient to put definitions into every translation unit, and thus common practice, it's not a requirement.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yup, you're right. However, it's quite rare to be able to do all required explicit instantiations "in advance."