# Force Qt Creator to parse and index -inl.h files

Tags: autocomplete, qt-creator, syntax-highlighting

In our company, we use some kind of modified version of the Google C++ code style. We use `Foo-inl.h`
file for template and inline functions in `Foo` class. You can read more about -inl files and why using them in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698235/when-should-i-use-inl-h-files).

Personally, I use Qt creator as the IDE for development, but unfortunately, Qt Creator does not parse and index -inl files. Hence you don't have autocompletion, usage, syntax highlighting and other feathers for functions defined there.

I want to make Qt Creator parse -inl files too.