# Issue implementing basic templates

Tags: c++, templates

Having read many links about setting up templates on classes I have got to this perplexing compiler error:

```
Linking...
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall test<int,int>::test<int,int>(int)" (??0?$test@HH@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The offending code, as simply as possible is:

test.h

```
template<typename U, typename V>
class test {
public:
    test(int number);
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

template<typename T, typename U>
test<T, U>::test(int number){}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

void main() {
    test<int, int> a = test<int, int>(4);
}
```

Clearly the previous code does nothing useful, I am simply building a model of templates to start a project. Can anyone explain what I'm not understanding about structuring this solution to meet the ends of having a templated class that can construct itself correctly?

Comment: This should be a duplication - put the template definition in the header

Answer (score 0):

move the implementation to the header.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way templates work, your implementation must be in the header file, not in a separate .cpp file. So your need this:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
class test {
public:
    test(int number)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides moving implementation to the header you can also use trick shown in the question at the link [template definition and declaration in separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)