# Passing a 3D array to a class (conversion problems)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates

I'm trying to write a class 'STFT' to perfom a short time FT. It calls the fftw3.h functions, which output a double*[2] array, and I want to create an array of these arrays. So I thought the following would be a suitable transform function (this is a stripped down version):

```
void STFT::Transform(double ***transform) {
//stuff
}
```

However, when I called it with say

```
transform[100][100][2]
```

I get the error message:

```
error: cannot convert double (*)[100][2]' to `double***
```

After looking around, I think I've found a solution using templates [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) but I'm having trouble implementing it, mainly in figuring out where I put the general type indicator 'T'. My updated functions are:

STFT.hpp

```
class STFT {

public:
  template<int N>
  void Transform(double transform[][N][2]);
};
```

STFT.cpp

```
using namespace std;

template<int N>

void STFT::Transform(double transform[][N][2]) {
  cout << "IT WORKS" << endl;
}
```

and the function call is in main.cpp:

```
STFT stft;
double transform[100][100][2];

stft.Transform(transform);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. The error message is:

```
undefined reference to `void STFT::Transform<100>(double (*) [100][2])
```

I imagine the problem lies in my naive implementation of templates. I've tried multiple different ways but I can't seem to get to a solution, if anyone can assist I'd be super grateful!

Comment: double*** and (*double)[][] are not the same thing.

Comment: The second compile error you are getting is because you are trying to define a template function in the .cpp file.

Comment: @pippin1289, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: self - correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought I was passing a double[][][] into a double[][N][2] parameter?

pippin - I deleted the template line but still encountering some troubles. I'll have another go and see if I get anywhere

Comment: @user3023621 while having your go at it, [read this question + answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) regarding where to implement template functions.

Comment: Also read up on [*three star programming*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: haha cheers for the link, I'm clearly a threetard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are tagging this as `C++`, but you are using C-style (and error prone) data storage. so use a "true" c++ solution: use the containers of the standard library.

Here, As far as I understand, you need a matrix of pair of values, so why not use for example:

```
typedef std::pair<double,double> myElements;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<myElements>> myContainer;
myContainer data; // instanciation
....
void STFT::Transform(myContainer& d) {
}
```

Populating the elements can be done this way:

```
for( size_t i=0; i<100; i++ )
{
    std::vector<myElements> new_vec;
    for( size_t j=0; j<100; j++ )
    {
        double val1 = ...;
        double val2 = ...;
        new_vec.push_back( std::make_pair(val1,val2) );
    }    
    data.push_back( new_vec );
}
```

If you are concerned with performance, you can preallocate the size of the vector to the number of elements.

If [`std::pair`](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) isn't comfortable, you can use [`std::array`](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that has the advantage of having a compile-time size:

```
 typedef std::array<double,2> myElements;
```

Then, instead of accessing with `.first` and `.second`, you just do:

```
data.at(i).at(j)[0] = ...;
data.at(i).at(j)[1] = ...;
```

or, if you are sure about your index values, and you dont want run-time bounds checking:

```
data[i][j][0] = ...;
data[i][j][1] = ...;
```

They are plenty of solutions, but **please**, forget about all these pointers and old-school memory allocation. I promise, I **also** used to program like this, I changed, and i am so glad that these containers exist, no more hours spend to debug either compile-time error messages , or run-time unexpected crashes.

And, no, if correctly used, there is (hardly) no timing overhead.

Comment: I give up using arrays, yours is a far more stable method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Trust me, you won't regret using the containers of the standard library. However, be warned that it can take some time to master them in depth...