# Function template instantiations not exported to other compilation units, if inlined?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm observing this peculiar phenomenon in which g++ will not export the template function instantiations if they're only used inlined.. This is not true for regular non-templated functions, of course. For example:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "inc.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << func<3>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << func2() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// inc.h
template<int num>
int func();

int func2();

// a.cpp
template<int num>
int func() {
    return num;
}

int func2() {
    return 5;
}

int result;
int result2;

void instantiate() {
    // store the results in globally visible variables
    // so the compiler won't optimize them out completely
    result = func<3>();
    result2 = func2();
}
```

If I compile the above with `-O0`, linking is successful - `objdump` confirms the binary code for both `func2` and `func<3>` is generated in `a.o` and `instantiate` is making two function calls, ie the functions are not being inlined.

However, `-O3` changes things - `instantiate` contains no function calls and `func<3>` is not generated in the assembly, causing a linker error. `func2` is still there, of course.

I was bitten by this in real code, expecting the functions to be exported and getting linker errors. Is this behavior expected? Could the compiler be convinced to generate the functions even if they're only used inline in the compilation unit they're implemented in? In my case we have many template specializations.. explicit instantiation would be impractical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Comment: *explicit instantiation would be impractical*: Why do you think so?

Comment: The code instantiates hundreds of specializations, soon to grow into the thousands. :P

Comment: Then put all your template code into the header files and don't worry.