# c++ function to return "zero" of the appropriate type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a zero() template function that will always return zero of the appropriate type. This is trivial for base types but I'd like similar behavior for user-defined types (which could provide their own overload). For example

```
auto i = zero<int>() // i is an in
auto d = zero<double>() // d is a double
auto m = zero<Matrix2d>() // m is a Matrix2d with all elements initialized to zero.
```

What I have is this:

```
template <typename T>
T zero() {
    return T{}*0; // Clearly not correct for all types, but known incorrect cases should be specialized
}

template <>
int zero<int>() { return 1; } // intentionally wrong for testing
```

but calling

```
cout << zero<int>() << endl;
```

is outputting 0 indicating the specialization is not being called. What am I doing wrong?

*NOTE: The use case is similar to std::accumulate, but imagine the starting value is always zero and we don't want to require the user to pass that in.

*UPDATE*
As a couple commentors noted, this works in Ideone. Something about my specific implementation is breaking it then. I have:

zero.h:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T zero() {
    return T{}*0;
}
```

zero.cpp:

```
#include "zero.h"
template <>
constexpr int zero<int>() { return 1; }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "zero.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "int: " << zero<int>() << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel called [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Just create a default constructor for your class, and be done with it.

Comment: Why not use a variable template? `template <typename T> constexpr T Zero = T{};`

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/T4al10)

Comment: No true: https://ideone.com/iGPOF0

Comment: I dont really understand how this is supposed to make it easier for the user. Isnt it easier to let the user choose the starting value as he wants and pass that in instead of forcing him to provide some overload/specialization?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as your problem is not reproducable with the code provided.

Comment: you're not declaring a specialisation in the header file. So the version in the .cpp file is not being referenced.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) is your issue.

Comment: `zero<int>() { return 1; }` wut?

Comment: @piwi the comment on that exact line is `// intentionally wrong for testing`. That's perfectly explanatory IMO.

Comment: @RichardHodges, prototypes for all specializes need to be put in the header too?

Comment: @davmac Oops my bad, I guess I crashed on the `return 1`

Comment: @NathanOliver, specializations should be able to go in .cpp files. The first answer on the link you give even has an example very similar to mine (template in header, specializations in .cpp)

Comment: @ryan0270 Those are instantiations, not specializations.

Comment: @ryan0270 the compilation unit calling zero<X>() needs to know that there is a specialisation of zero<X> for it's X, otherwise it will simply generate zero<X> inline. Then you will have two definitions of the function. one in your compilation unit's object file and the other in zero.o. Which one gets linked? undefined.

Comment: What does `T{}` do for the 2D matrix? Do you really need this at all, instead of just using value initialization?

Comment: @RichardHodges, I think I can work with that. It's annoying, but not any more so than templates in general. Can you put that as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @ryan0270 biagio's answer covers it. it's not a template problem, it's just that compilation units are compiled in isolation, so they need complete information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using templates in *".cpp"* files.
Some useful [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file).

Try to move everything into the header file:

*zero.h:*

```
template <typename T>
T zero() {
    return T{}*0;
}

template <>
int zero<int>() { return 1; }
```

And delete the file *zero.cpp*.

## EDIT:

If you're using Visual Studio, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx7k7hcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) could be useful:

> This error will also be generated as a result of compiler conformance work that was done in Visual Studio .NET 2003:. For code will be valid in the Visual Studio .NET 2003 and Visual Studio .NET versions of Visual C++, remove template <>.

Answer (score 2):

Never use template function specialization.  Well almost never.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

This lets us pass types around as values.

```
namespace utility{
  template<class T>
  T zero(){ return zero(tag<T>);}

  template<class T>
  T zero( tag_t<T> ) { return T{}*0; }
}
```

Now to add support for specific types the default implementation does not work for, simply override `zero(tag_t<X>)` in either the namespace of `X` (or in `utility` for types in `std` or built-in types).

```
namespace math{
  struct matrix2d; // define it
  inline matrix2d zero( tag_t<matrix2d> ){ return matrix2d::zero; }
}
```

ADL will find the correct zero if you `utility::zero<X>()`.

Specialization of template functions works like neither overloading nor specialization of template types.  It is fragile and its rules are unique to it; it is very rarely the best solution to any problem.  Avoid it.

As template function specialization is fragile, it does not surprise me some detail not show broke your example: the code posted in the OP does not obviously break when naively transcribed.  It is still a bad idea: on top of fragiliity, it also forces people writing code in namespace bob to exit it, add a specialization of zero in its namespace, then come back to namespace bob.  While doing so the base specializtion of zero must be visible, messing with dependencies.  It gets aweful.

Comment: I'm aware there are strange rules with respect to function template speciallization, but it this case I'm specifically trying to avoid passing in an argument. Othersize I'd just do: template <typename T> T zero(const T& ex) and do basic overloading: int zero(const int& ex) { return 1; }

Comment: sorry, I ready through it too fast so see the line that does that.

Answer (score 0):

"The use case is similar to `std::accumulate`, but imagine the starting value is always zero and we don't want to require the user to pass that in."

As it happens, I have exactly that in my toolbox:

```
template <typename FwdIter>
inline auto accumulate(FwdIter begin, FwdIter end) 
        -> typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::value_type
{
    return std::accumulate(begin, end,
      typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::value_type());
}
```

The relevant expression is `typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::value_type()` which calculates the zero value given just the iterator type. You need the `typename` because `value_type` is a dependent type.

Answer (score -1):

Use default constructor of type `T` or use `0` argument:

```
template <class T>
T zero()
{
    return T() /* or T(0)*/;
}
```

Comment: IMO this post does not answer the question. I agree with you your *"style"* is more robust in certain sense, but the question is "why does that code print 0, instead of 1".

Comment: @BiagioFesta That is not answerable as the op needs a MCVE.  As you and another have shown what the OP says he gets is not reproduce-able.

Comment: @NathanOliver Exactly, the fact that there is no answer to that question proves more this post does not answer the question