# No matching function for template class operator in C++ with .hpp and .cpp

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, template-classes

I have two files that I would like to compile. They are as follows:

Array.hpp

```
template<class T> class Array 
{
    public:
        Array() {};
        ~Array() {};

        int width_, height_;
        std::vector<T> data_;

        template<typename U>
        void print(const Array<U>& inputArray);

        T* operator()(int x, int y);
}
```

Array.cpp

```
template<typename T> template<typename U>
void Array<T>::print(const Array<U>& inputArray)
{
    std::cout << ( *inputArray(0, 0) ) << std::endl; 
// ERROR: No matching function for call to object of type 'const Array<unsigned char>'
} 
template void Array<uint8_t>::print(const Array<uint8_t>& inputArray);
template void Array<uint8_t>::print(const Array<float>& inputArray);


template <typename T>
T* Array<T>::operator()(int x, int y)
{
    return &data_[0] + x + y*width_;
}
template uint8_t* Array<uint8_t>::operator()(int x, int y);
template float* Array<float>::operator()(int x, int y);
```

It is completely unclear to me why a call to the operator is throwing an error. The operator is clearly defined for both inputs types that are instantiated for function "print".
Is it because the compiler is looking in the header files first and can't find an instance of the operator with the specified type.
Defining the operator in the header file wouldn't do much good either. This (as far as my knowledge reaches) again would raise an error as there are two functions (operators) implemented in the header file with the same name but different return types.

What to do?

Comment: ps. I am aware of the fact that the actual functioning of the code is utterly ridiculous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but can't `print` just be a free function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function

```
void Array<T>::print(const Array<U>& inputArray)
```

accepts const reference, while method that it is calling:

```
T* operator()(int x, int y);
```

is not const hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is `void print(const Array<U>& inputArray);` is not `const` but `void Array<T>::print(const Array<U>& inputArray) const` is. These are not the same functions. Perhaps you intended to make `print` static, since it doesn't use `this`?

The second problem is that the operator `T* operator()(int x, int y);` is not `const` but `const Array<U>& inputArray` is. `inputArray` can only call `const` methods.

There are many other problems with your code, but either of these is likely causing your error message.