# A C++ templated function issue

Tags: c++11, templates

I have a problem with a Template function inside a class. When I call "Set" in something() function, VS show me: 
Error   C2275   'T': illegal use of this type as an expression

The header is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using t_double = double;
template<typename T>
using t_vec = std::vector<T>;

class SuperPixel2
{
    t_vec<double> distances;

    template<typename T>
    void Set(t_vec<T> &v,
    size_t i,
    size_t j,
    const T &val);

    void something();
}
```

And the cpp file:

```
#include "SuperPixel2.h"
template<typename T>
void SuperPixel2::Set(t_vec<T> &v,
    size_t i,
    size_t j,
    const T &val)
{
    v[i * cols + j] = T;
}

void SuperPixel2::something()
{
    t_double d;
    //..
    Set(distances, k, l, (t_double)d);
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what sudo make install said, you generally cannot declare a template in a header file and write the implementation in a cpp file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) for an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well this line looks pretty odd:

```
v[i * cols + j] = T;
```

I think it's meant to be:

```
v[i * cols + j] = val;
```

As a side note (and maybe this would make more sense looking at the whole class), the type of `distances` is known (a vector of doubles), so it's unclear to me why the `Set` method needs to be a templated member.