# Specialize template class for different parameter sets

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Suppose I have a template struct like

```
template <typename T> struct Parser {
  //specializations are expected to have these methods
  inline static const byte* objectEnd(const byte* begin, const byte* end);
  inline static const byte* tryRead(const byte* begin, const byte* end, T* obj);
}
```

It is used in different classes, some of which are also template classes (so they may not have full info about what class they pass to `Parser` as a parameter).
Implementing `Parser` for any given type is easy, like this:

```
template<> struct Parser<text_line> {
  inline static const byte* objectEnd(const byte* begin, const byte* end){
    return helper::NextByteOrEnd<'\n'>(begin, end);
  }
  inline static const byte* tryRead(const byte* begin const byte* end, text_line* obj){
    const byte* lf = objectEnd(begin, end);
    obj = text_line(begin, lf);
    return lf==end ? lf : lf+1;
  }
}
```

I can specialize `Parser` for a family of templates, as well:

```
template<int sz> struct Parser<be_uint<sz>> {
  inline static const byte* objectEnd(const byte* begin, const byte* end){
    return begin+be_uint<sz>::size > end ? begin : begin+be_uint<sz>::size;
  }
  inline static const byte* tryRead(const byte* begin const byte* end, be_uint<sz>* obj){
    if(begin + be_uint<sz>::size > end) return begin;
    obj = be_uint<sz>::read(begin);
    return begin + be_uint<sz>::size;
  }
}
```

But what if I want to specialize `Parser` for some other set of types? Suppose I have a type predicate, say, `std::is_base_of<MyHeader, T>` and I want to write something like

```
//not actual code - how would I write this?
template<typename Header> struct Parser<Header> {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<MyHeader, Header>::value, "Wrong!");
  inline static const byte* objectEnd(const byte* begin, const byte* end){
    //MyHeader-specific code here
  }
  inline static const byte* tryRead(const byte* begin const byte* end, Header* obj){
    //MyHeader-specific code here
  }
}
```

Adding optional parameters to the initial definition of `Parser`, like

```
template <typename T, bool MyHeaderFlag = std::is_base_of<MyHeader, T>::value>
struct Parser { //...
```

doesn't seem like a good idea - I (or any other programmer) may want to use other predicates, say, `my_types::is_scientific<T>`.
The problem seems like something you could resolve with SFINAE (there's a problem of what should happen if one type fits several predicates - I prefer that it wouldn't result in compiler error, but it isn't very important since such `Parser` specializations are likely to be palced in .cpp-files). But I couldn't find a way to do this.

Just to be clear, there is no constraint on preserving the exact definition of `Parser' or its methods (or even it being a template), as long as client code can write something like

```
Parser<TypeArg>::objectEnd(block.begin, block.begin+block.size)
```

without caring what `TypeArg` actually is.

Comment: Don't store template functions in cpp-files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Comment: @Jonas If I write the whole template specialization (_including declaration_) in .cpp file, how exactly that is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make specialization for some set of types, best way is to add second template parameter to your base template.

You can do that with `bool`, or with actually type and use `std::enable_if` in specializations.

I prefer the second way.

```
template <typename T, typename = void> struct Parser {
  //specializations are expected to have these methods
  inline static const byte* objectEnd(const byte* begin, const byte* end);
  inline static const byte* tryRead(const byte* begin, const byte* end, T* obj);
}
```

and specialization example

```
template<typename Header>
struct Parser<Header, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<MyHeader, Header>::value>::type> {
  inline static const byte* objectEnd(const byte* begin, const byte* end){
    //MyHeader-specific code here
  }
  inline static const byte* tryRead(const byte* begin, const byte* end, Header* obj){
    //MyHeader-specific code here
  }
}
```