# Does template explicit instantiation work with forward-declared-types?

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration, explicit-instantiation

If I have a template class with some method defined in the .cpp file instead of the .h file, I can use explicit instantiation to get the compiler to avoid unresolved externals.

But would it work if the explicit instantiation is declared using a forward-declared type ?

```
template <typename T> struct Template
{
  void someFunc(); //defined in the .cpp file
}

class A;

template Template<A>;
```

Would it work if `A` is finally not defined and `Template<A>` not used ?

Comment: Just don't split the template and define it all in a header file.

Comment: There's no use of `A` that require it to be complete here, so there's no issue anyway.

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks for your answer. If this code is part of a library, the Template<A>::someFunc() symbol would then be exported in the lib and not cause an unresolved external later on, when A is defined ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Comment: I have seen this question but how does it relate to the forward declaration of the type for which the explicit instantiation is made ?

Comment: Stackoverflow does not accept just a "yes"

Comment: @dgrat Thank you very much for this "yes" which answers my question.
Maybe you could elaborate on how it works ? I think that what puzzles me is how the symbol can be generated on a forward-declaration, i.e. without knowing the size in memory of these objects.
Does it mean that we can generate a pool of symbols for a template and afterwards alias classes to match the elements of this pool ? (I'm not suggesting that it would be a good idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. The compiler only generates code if the template is instantiated (in your example no code is generated because there is no instantiation). Second, you pass a type template argument. Here the compiler would be allowed to safely create an instance. 
In your example you do not use the type somewhere, but if you would e.g. to define a function, my first sentence would apply again, and the function is just generated upon instantiation somewhere.
Just at this moment the compiler must have all the knowledge to generate the code.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>


template <typename T> struct Template
{
  void someFunc(); //defined in the .cpp file
};

class A;
Template<A> foo;
```

However, if you create a template taking a non-type parameter. It will fail because the type definition is incomplete, as you were concerned of.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A;

template <A parm> struct Template
{
  void someFunc() {
        parm.foo();   
  }
};

A a;
using foo = Template<a>;
```

The same for this example. Here you would create an object `a` and of course the compiler needs to know more about the type. This is why it fails.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>


template <typename T> struct Template
{
  T a;
};

class A;
Template<A> foo;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was in a case where in another project, when defining a specialization of this template for a new type, I had (as expected) an unresolved external, as the function is defined in the body. So in that other project I was effectively using this template, but with a symbol that did not exist at the time of the definition of the template, and that would not be defined before the lib file is created. With that forward-definition trick, I don't have that unresolved external any more and I wonder why. I believed that the body of template functions had to be in the cpp so that the size is known.