# How do I realise a Template for a recursive function that allows many parameters of undefined datatypes in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I want to create a C++ Template for a function, that allows per default intinity arguments of any datatypes. I found some examples where they try to Code the printf function but it doesn't work (they included stdarg.h, i want something like that:)

```
    //util.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    template<typename ...Args>
    void debugPrint(Args... args)
    {
        // pseudo: foreach args as a:
        std::cout << a;
        // pseudo: endforeach
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //util.hpp
    template<typename ...Args> //?
    void debugPrint(Args...);

    //app.cpp
    #include "util.hpp"
    int main()
    {
        debugPrint("Hallo", " ", "Welt", 1, 2, "\t", 2.3);
        return 0;
    }
```

Want the consoleoutput:
Hallo Welt12 [TAB] 2.3

Then there were an examplte with stdarg.h

```
    #include <stdarg.h>

    void tprintf(const char* format) // base function
    {
        std::cout << format;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Targs>
    void tprintf(const char* format, T value, Targs... Fargs) // recursive function
    {
        for (; *format != '\0'; format++) {
            if (*format == '%') {
                std::cout << value;
                tprintf(format + 1, Fargs...); // recursive call
                return;
            }
            std::cout << *format;
        }
    }
```

So how? :(

Thanks for any answere <3

Comment: And see also [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1362568)

Answer (score 4):

As with any recursive solution, you need a base case to terminate the recursion. In this situation the base case is when there are no arguments left to print, in which case you do nothing:

```
void debugPrint() { }
```

Then the recursive template function, which processes a single "first" argument and then recurses on the remaining variadic arguments:

```
template <typename FirstArg, typename ...Args>
void debugPrint(FirstArg arg, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << arg;
    debugPrint(args...);
}
```

Tying it all together:

```
#include <iostream>

void debugPrint() { }

template <typename FirstArg, typename ...Args>
void debugPrint(FirstArg arg, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << arg;
    debugPrint(args...);
}

int main()
{
    debugPrint("Hallo", " ", "Welt", 1, 2, "\t", 2.3);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hallo Welt12    2.3
```

Comment: Nice answer! Just adding my two cents: traditionally, the first element is called the _head_ and the rest is the _tail_ :) `template<class Head, class... Tail>`

Comment: Thanks! It works, but when I try to give it a Namespace and outsource the Code in a util.h and util.cpp I got also an error :/

Comment: @j0ta Note that [templates must (usually) be defined in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file), putting it in a `.cpp` isn't likely to work. If that thread doesn't help you, consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fold expressions to do that (C++17):

```
template<typename... Args>
void debugPrint(Args const&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

It will expand `args` with a `<<` between expanded expressions. There is no need for recursion.

[Here's a live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zw5bUx).

Comment: From C++17 on..

Comment: @PaulSanders I don't see a `c++14` or a `c++11` tag, and the question don't mention a version. I assume a up to date version.