# Templated covariance function in Eigen

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

One of my projects requires a templated covariance function, i.e. taking a MatrixXd, ArrayXXf and/or a .block() thereof as input and returning an expression to be used in further calculations.

q1. As verification, my attempt below seems to work, but does it actually return an Eigen expression? (edit: @Darhuuk confirmed it does not; fortunately, C++14 or higher is not a problem!)

q2. Obviously, I'd need something of an 'internal Matrix' rather than the internal RowVector I came across in the Eigen documentation about templated functions. Hence my question, how should one create an internal MatrixType z = x.rowwise() - x.colwise().mean(), so the function can return (z.transpose()*z)/(x.rows()-1)? The internal rowvector is used in the covariance examples in the Eigen manual (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)

q3. Finally, when adding the templated function to a class with a header file, how do I find which Eigen types need to be used to explicitly instantiate the template for e.g. MatrixXd, a .block() of an ArrayXXd, or a Map? All I could find were examples using simple data types (e.g. [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file))

```
template <typename Derived>
Matrix<typename Derived::Scalar, Derived::ColsAtCompileTime, Derived::ColsAtCompileTime>  
SampleCov( const DenseBase<Derived>& x )
{

  typedef typename internal::plain_row_type<Derived>::type RowVectorType;
  const RowVectorType x_mean = x.colwise().mean();

  return ((x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix().transpose() * (x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix()) / (x.rows()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function explicitly returns a `Matrix` object, so no, it does not return an expression object. One way to fix this is by letting the compiler deduce the return type for you (since the expression object will be some gigantic templated mess):

```
template <typename Derived>
auto SampleCov (DenseBase<Derived> const & x) {
  auto const x_mean = x.colwise().mean();
  return ((x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix().transpose()
    * (x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix()) / (x.rows() - 1);
}
```

This is assuming you're using C++14 or higher. For C++11 using just auto as the return type doesn't cut it, you need a trailing return type:

```
template <typename Derived>
auto SampleCov (DenseBase<Derived> const & x)
    -> decltype(((x.rowwise() - x.colwise().mean()).matrix().transpose()
      * (x.rowwise() - x.colwise().mean()).matrix()) / (x.rows() - 1)) {
  auto const x_mean = x.colwise().mean();
  return ((x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix().transpose()
    * (x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix()) / (x.rows() - 1);
}
```

Note that I removed the `RowVectorType` typedef, since I didn't see the point.

Regarding question 2, I think the above examples solve that issue, since there's no more explicitly named types. The `auto` for both the return type and inside the function takes care of that.

Finally, question 3. It depends on what exactly you want to do. Based on what you're saying, it seems the above functions don't work for `MatrixXd` objects or objects returned by calling `MatrixXd::block()`.

To me that doesn't really indicate that you need [explicit template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation), which is what you're asking.

Instead, you could simply make `SampleCov`'s argument type more generic:

```
template <typename T>
auto SampleCovGeneric (T const & x) {
  auto const x_mean = x.colwise().mean();
  return ((x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix().transpose()
    * (x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix()) / (x.rows() - 1);
}
```

As long as you can call `colwise()`, `matrix()`, ... on an object of type `T`, you're good to go. This is probably a better way to go anyway, since now it's possible to pass in Eigen expressions to `SampleCovGeneric`. For example:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd a(2,2);

// aTranspose is NOT a matrix object!
// Its type is Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>>.
auto aTranspose = a.transpose();

/* Note use of auto and eval() calls!
 * See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html.
 */
auto b = SampleCov(aTranspose.eval()).eval();
auto c = SampleCovGeneric(aTranspose).eval();
```

In the above example, `SampleCov` expects an object of type `DenseBase<Derived>`. But `aTranspose` is not such a type. So we have to explicitly evaluate (i.e. actually calculate) the transpose first. Depending on what happens inside `SampleCov` that's a useless calculation. E.g. imagine the first thing calculated is the argument (`x`) its transpose. In this case that would simply be the original a again. But if the transpose is already evaluated then Eigen can't "see" that and needs to calculate the transpose's transpose.

`SampleCovGeneric` on the other hand accepts any type, so there's no need to evaluate `aTranspose` first. That (might) allow Eigen to "see through" a bunch of calculations and thus calculate the result in a more optimized manner. See e.g. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html.

If you really need to, you can [explicitly instantiate templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation) so they can be split in header & source files. That would go something like this:

```
/* Header */
#pragma once

#include <utility>

// Reduce trailing return type mess a little
template <class T>
using SampleCovResultType = decltype(((std::declval<T const &>().rowwise()
      - std::declval<T const &>().colwise().mean()).matrix().transpose()
    * (std::declval<T const &>().rowwise()
      - std::declval<T const &>().colwise().mean()).matrix())
  / (std::declval<T const &>().rows() - 1));

template <typename T>
auto SampleCov (T const & x) -> SampleCovResultType<T>;

// Explicit template declaration
extern template
auto SampleCov<Eigen::MatrixXd> (Eigen::MatrixXd const & x)
    -> SampleCovResultType<Eigen::MatrixXd>;

/* Source */
#include "SampleCov.h"

template <class T>
auto SampleCov (T const & x) -> SampleCovResultType<T> {
  auto const x_mean = x.colwise().mean();
  return ((x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix().transpose()
    * (x.rowwise() - x_mean).matrix()) / (x.rows() - 1);
}

// Explicit template definition
template
auto SampleCov<Eigen::MatrixXd> (Eigen::MatrixXd const & x)
    -> SampleCovResultType<Eigen::MatrixXd>;
```

I don't think you can get away with using only auto as the return type. Since the function definition is put into a separate source file, the compiler can't see the function body, so it has no way to deduce the return type when you call the function. So you have to use a trailing return type.

Note the following though:

> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) prevents
>   implicit instantiations: the code that would otherwise cause an
>   implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation
>   definition provided somewhere else in the program.

I.e. if you try to call `SampleCov` with a type `T` for which you did not explicitly instantiate `SampleCov`, compilation will fail.

*Note:* All of the above code is untested. Chance of typos is high :).

**Edits:**

- Fixing missing template argument.
- Removed remark about calling `matrix()`. I wondered whether it evaluated the expression, which you don't want it to do. AFAIK, it does not, based on e.g. [ArrayBase's documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#af01e9ea8087e390af8af453bbe4c276c).
- Added info about explicit instantiation.

Comment: Hi Darhuuk, I tried to compile an example based on your code, but gcc complains that "Derived is not declared in this scope". I used the .matrix() in my example code to allow for potential ArrayXXd inputs. Question 2 is about storing an intermediate calculation in matrix instead of vector form (the Eigen manual covar example uses an internal rowVector, perhaps there is an internal Matrix type?). Question 3 is similar to the error I get when using this function as a template; how do instantiate the templated function for e.g. MatrixXd or a block from a MatrixXd?

Comment: @Marzz Wow, must have been tired. I totally missed that template argument. Let me go and update the code.

Comment: Hi Darhuuk, thanks! I look forward to testing the auto-type approach but how do I explicitly instantiate the templated function for Eigen-specific data types in classes with separate header and cpp files (i.e. the third question)? All examples I could find were using standard data types, as in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Comment: @Marzz See edit, that should do it. The question is though: do you really need to split the declaration & definition? I'd say this is generally only necessary if you're running into slow compilation due to template instantiation.

Comment: Hi Darhuuk, the templated version that accepts Eigen types is indeed far less straightforward than the examples I've found thus far, but I'm sure I'll need it for some of my other functions, so many thanks!

Comment: @Marzz Glad I could help!