# Template class with only static methods Implementation using .cpp file giving error

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to implement a class in C++ which contains most of the functions which I might need to use across different class hierarchies (the project has multiple different inheritance trees).

After reading through and taking advise from multiple answers for this kind of implementation on [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file), [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) I decided to implement this using a .h file and 2 different .cpp files. I tried to implement a small test case using this FAQ as a [guideline](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl). The code is as below:

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

template<typename T> 
class test{
public:
static bool IsClose(const T &a, const T &b);
};
#endif
```

**testImpl.h**

```
#include "test.h"

template <typename T> 
bool test<T>::IsClose(const T &a, const T &b){
    return (std::abs(a-b) <= (1e-8 + 1e-5 * std::abs(b)));
}
```

**testImpl.cpp**

```
#include "testImpl.h"

template class test<int>;
template class test<double>;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iomanip>
int main(){
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << test<double>::IsClose(1e-7,1.1e-7) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling using `g++ -o test main.cpp testImpl.cpp` I'm getting the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:4:36: error: ‘test’ is not a template
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << test<double>::IsClose(1e-7,1.1e-7) << std::endl;
```

If anyone can advise me on where I'm going wrong your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!! Also if there is a better method to achieve what I'm trying to do, your thoughts are welcome on that matter as well.

Comment: put all of your template code in headers. Just the explicit template specialization implementations should be in cpp

Comment: @bolov @Elliot I changed the name of ```test.cpp``` to ```testImpl.h``` but still have the same error.

Comment: Does it compile if you place all the source in a single file? Which g++ version are you using? Also, like @Elliott suggested, try renaming __TEST_H__ not to use leading or trailing underscores.

Comment: @Eugene it compiles when I put everything in a single source file. I'm using g++ version 7.5.0 and I tried removing the leading and trailing underscores but to no effect. Also I tried this code as template functions instead of template class and it compiled fine.

Comment: @Elliot I changed that too in the code. Removed the leading and trailing underscores.... But sadly I still have the same error.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. What's your cpu and OS?

Comment: @Elliot Ubuntu 18.04 and CPU is a i7 8th generation.

Comment: @DewanArunSingh, weird. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and and i7 8th gen also (i7-8550U).

Comment: What does `gcc -v` give you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226338/discussion-between-dewan-arun-singh-and-elliott).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. I needed to let the compiler know that it needs to use a more recent version of C++. So,  `g++ -std=c++17 -o test main.cpp testImpl.cpp` compiled the code for me perfectly fine.

The need for using -std flag arises only when you're using the gcc version 7.5.0. All versions of gcc after it, work with the `g++ -o test main.cpp testImpl.cpp`.

Comment: This helps to solve the problem, but doesn't explain why it wasn't compiling in the first place. That's still a mystery (possibly a bug in GCC 7.5.0, known or unknown). Also, you're welcome, but there's no need to thank anyone in your answer. Stackoverflow is supposed to be very blunt.  =P

Comment: @Elliot it seems you were right, THIS is a bug in gcc 7.5.0 I tried the same code with gcc 10.1.0 and it worked without the -std flag.