# Linker error when compiling simple class with type template. Without the template it works. What am I missing?

Tags: c++, linker, g++, clang++

Linker error when compiling simple C++ class with type template. Without the template it works. What am I missing?

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 \
    src/main/c/MyCompany/MyProject/Util/GenericNamespaceExample.cpp \
    src/main/c/TestGenericNamespaceExample.cpp \
    -o src/main/c/TestGenericNamespaceExample
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<double>::setValue(double)", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<double>::GenericExampleClass(double)", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<double>::~GenericExampleClass()", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<int>::GenericExampleClass()", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<int>::~GenericExampleClass()", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<double>::display() const", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<double>::getValue() const", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
  "MyCompany::MyProject::Util::GenericExampleClass<int>::display() const", referenced from:
      _main in TestGenericNamespaceExample-3bb482.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
$ tree src/main/c
src/main/c
├── MyCompany
│   └── MyProject
│       └── Util
│           ├── GenericNamespaceExample.cpp
│           └── GenericNamespaceExample.h
└── TestGenericNamespaceExample.cpp
```

```cpp
// FILE: src/main/c/MyCompany/MyProject/Util/GenericNamespaceExample.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

namespace MyCompany::MyProject::Util {

    template <typename T>
    class GenericExampleClass {
    private:
        T value;

    public:
        GenericExampleClass();
        GenericExampleClass(T initialValue);
        ~GenericExampleClass();

        void setValue(T newValue);
        T getValue() const;

        void display() const;
    };

}
```

```cpp
// FILE: src/main/c/MyCompany/MyProject/Util/GenericNamespaceExample.cpp
#include "GenericNamespaceExample.h"

namespace MyCompany::MyProject::Util {

    template <typename T>
    GenericExampleClass<T>::GenericExampleClass() : value(T()) {}

    template <typename T>
    GenericExampleClass<T>::GenericExampleClass(T initialValue) : value(initialValue) {}

    template <typename T>
    GenericExampleClass<T>::~GenericExampleClass() {}

    template <typename T>
    void GenericExampleClass<T>::setValue(T newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T GenericExampleClass<T>::getValue() const {
        return value;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void GenericExampleClass<T>::display() const {
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    }

}
```

```cpp
// FILE: src/main/c/TestGenericNamespaceExample.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MyCompany/MyProject/Util/GenericNamespaceExample.h"

using namespace MyCompany::MyProject::Util;

int main() {
    GenericExampleClass<int> obj1;
    obj1.display();

    GenericExampleClass<double> obj2(42.5);
    obj2.display();

    obj2.setValue(99.9);
    std::cout << "Updated Value: " << obj2.getValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile with:

```
$ g++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Also tried in Linux but it does not work. It does not look like it is OS dependent.

I can get it to work without the template. But with the template it does not work.

I've been trying to make it work for hours. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643183/c-template-class-header-implementation-functions-involving-the-template-clas resembles your problem closer (a template class) but ultimately links back to the same resource: templates can only be implemented in the header file

Comment: Thanks @Tas, but I'm kind of a newbie. That answer went over my head :( I cannot have any template implementation in the CPP file?

Comment: You can. The links have that answer.

Comment: If you are a newbie you may want to take the easy route and just put the template implementation in the header. If you have additional time and want to learn a workaround for a known set of types that are instantiated in the cpp file you can try to understand the "Alternative solution" of this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/495056/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495056/487892)