# C++ including Template class in multiple files

Tags: c++, templates, include, linker-errors

This is a follow up question to [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file).

I have a similar problem, using a template class across multiple files, each using the class. In the end they meet in main.cpp and therefore cause a linker error.

The difference to the post above is, that my template doesn't use a type, but a number as its template argument. And putting an instantiation of every possible number in the .cpp file doesn't seem to be a praticable solution ...

**someTemplate.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <array>


template<const size_t S>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo( const std::array<int, S>& someArr );
    int& get( const int index );

private:
    std::array<int, S> arr;
};


template<size_t S>
inline Foo<S>::Foo()
{
}

template<size_t S>
inline Foo<S>::Foo( const std::array<int, S>& someArr ) : arr( someArr )
{
}

template<size_t S>
inline int& Foo<S>::get( const int index )
{
    return arr.at( index );
}
```

**otherFile.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "someTemplate.hpp"

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    Foo<3> doSome( Foo<3>& foo, int m );
};
```

**otherFile.cpp**

```
#include "otherFile.hpp"

Bar::Bar()
{
}

Foo<3> Bar::doSome( Foo<3>& foo, int m )
{
    Foo<3> foo;
    foo.get( 0 ) = m * foo.get( 0 );
    foo.get( 1 ) = m * foo.get( 1 );
    foo.get( 2 ) = m * foo.get( 2 );

    return foo;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "otherFile.hpp"
#include "someTemplate.hpp"

int main()
{
    Foo<3> foo1( { 1, 2, 3 } );
    Bar bar;
    Foo<3> foo2 = bar.doSome( foo1, 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: testing, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Main.cpp
1>otherFile.cpp
1>D:\Home\Documents\Programming\C++\Visual Studio 2019\testing\otherFile.cpp(10,12): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'foo'
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "testing.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So I can't split the class into definition and declaration, because the compiler won't find it? I can't put it into a single .hpp, because the definition gets included multiple times? But I have to include it into multiple files, because every translation unit needs it. So the question is ...

**How can one include a template class into multiple files?**

[ PS: The actual code is much bigger, containing templated functions and specializations. I just constructed this simple version for the post. ]

*using MSVC ++17 x64*

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the linker error?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: 

1>------ Build started: Project: testing, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Main.cpp
1>otherFile.cpp
1>D:\Home\Documents\Programming\C++\Visual Studio 2019\testing\otherFile.cpp(10,12): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'foo'
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "testing.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66752217/edit) this into your question

Comment: The error seems pretty explicit. You define `Foo<3> foo` in `Bar::doSome` which is redefining the parameter also named `foo`. Don't do that.