# How can I fix this clang error when compiling in c++?

Tags: c++

[Terminal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poSg4.png)

I am getting a compiler error I am not familiar with when trying to make my program. If anyone could be of any help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please read this, and especially note the part about *not* posting images: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. It takes more effort to upload and link a picture than it does to copy and paste it into a markdown block in your question, which allows others to copy and paste the text, search the text, and read the text as needed

Comment: Also the straight-forward question: Did you **define** `BrowserHistoryList::navigateTo` anywhere? That'd be a good place to start. You haven't provided enough information for anyone to know whether this is an error from incomplete code, or an error from an inadequate series of build commands.

Comment: LinkedList is a template class, right? If so, it needs to be [defined in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115735/1424875), not in its own compilation unit.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1387438

Comment: `LinkedList::length` is not implemented or not placed in header as most templates should.