# Templating a List in C++

Tags: c++, templating

I'm writing a program that needs a SkipList that I wrote a while back, but now I need it templated because it needs to use a custom class that I created. The problem I have is with creating the node in the List class. I use `template <class t>` on all my methods but I think that since both the node and the SkipList class use `template <class t>`, the same `class t`s interfere with each other or something.

In my SkipList.h, I have the method saying

```
Node <t>* createnode<t>(t,int);
```

And in the SkipList.cpp, the method says

```
template <class t>
Node<t>* SkipList<t>::createnode(t value, int level) {
    Node<t> *n = new Node<t>(value, level);
    return n;
}
```

This gives me an error in the .h file that says `Template specialization requires 'template<>'`, and when I add it in, it replaces the code to say

```
template<> Node<t>* createnode<t>(t,int);
```

But then my .cpp file says that there is no function definition anymore.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing? Thanks a ton for the help.
My GitHub is [here](https://github.com/K3ll3nL/Prime-Number-Finder) if anyone needs it for clarification

Comment: Seems you are trying to declare a template in a `.cpp` file. That will not work. This is not your issue here but important nevertheless See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Comment: Two other nuggets of info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice, one for `bits/stdc++` and one for `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1):

Few things to note:

- [You can't define templates in `.cpp` files use headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file).
- `using namespace std;` can and [will lead to nasty things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) especially when included in a header like this.
- [You shouldn't include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) `bits/stdc++.h`.

Now to address some things in the code. I am not sure if `template <class t, class t>` is valid, but at best it is useless in this case. Addressing your question: Yes the two `class t`s interfere with each other, but you don't need two different `t`s. You can't create a `Node<t>` with a `t` not matching the type of the `List` can you? Now even if you have a case where that is needed you can just use `template <class T1, class T2>`.

Now the fixed implementation would look like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
class SkipList {
    int MAX_LEVEL;
    float p;
    Node<t>* header;
    int level;
public:
    SkipList<T>(int,float) { /* Include definition here */}
    int randomlevel() { /* Include definition here */}
    void insert(T) { /* Include definition here */}
    void remove(T) { /* Include definition here */}
    bool find(T) { /* Include definition here */}
    void print() { /* Include definition here */}
    Node<T>* createnode(T, int) { /* Include definition here */}
};
```

Similarly `Node` should be fixed as well (include the definition of the constructor).

An other thing you mentioned in your post is template specialisation. You can read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

You also have a memory leak somewhere between your `Node`/`SkipList` classes. Consider moving to smart pointers.

[Finally I strongly encourage that you go through the basics of C++ before you continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You can't run before you can walk.