# Explicit instantiantion of template member in cpp file doesn't generate symbol (i.e. link error)

Tags: c++, templates

Take the following example:

```cpp
// A.h
class A
{
public:
    int v = 2;

    template <typename T>
    int f(T t);
};
```

```cpp
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"

template <typename T>
int A::f(T t)
{
    return v + t;
}

template <>
int A::f<int>(int t);
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A a;
    printf("%d\n", a.f(3));
    return 0;
}
```

When building this with `clang -std=c++14` (or g++), I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `int A::f<int>(int)'
```

Indeed, `nm A.o` doesn't show any symbols. Why didn't the explicit instantiation of `A::f<int>` inside `A.cpp` actually instantiate the function?

Comment: I did see this answer, which doesn't quite answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/115735/912144

Comment: Actually, just noticed that with `template A::f<int>...` it works, but not `template<> A::f<int>...`. What's the deal with the lack of `<>`?

Comment: With `<>` is [Explicit (full) template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). Without `<>` is [Function template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation). Details matter!

Comment: That's a declaration of a specialization, which is never defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @JaMiT got the answer.

```
template <> int A::f<int>(int t)
{
    // full specialization of templated thing
}
```

Is a full specialization.

```
template <> int A::f<int>(int t);
```

Is a declaration that such a specialization exists, but doesn't provide the definition.

The form you want is

```
 template int A::f<int>(int t);
```

Which is an instantiation of the member function.