# Undefined symbol when using a templated class in Objective-C++ (.mm) file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, templates, objective-c++

This is an Objective-C macOS project created with Xcode version 13.2.1. Inside the project, I have a templated class named "plistModifier". The class is meant to set custom types of values for any plist (e.g. `NSString`, `NSNumber` etc.). The header file of the class is called "plistModifier.h" and it looks like this:

```objectivec
#ifndef plistModifier_h
#define plistModifier_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <unistd.h>

template <class type>
class plistModifier {
       
public:
    void modifyPref(std::string key, type value);
    type getPref(std::string key);
};


#endif /* plistModifier_h */
```

The implementation of the class is as follows in a seperate "plistModifier.mm" file:

```objectivec
#include "plistModifier.h"

template <class type>
void plistModifier<type>::modifyPref(std::string key, type val) {
    
    NSString* preferencePlist = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/com.rA9.LeetDownPreferences.plist"];
    NSDictionary* dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:preferencePlist];
    [dict setValue:val forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:val]];
    [dict writeToFile:preferencePlist atomically:YES];
    
}
template <class type>
type plistModifier<type>::getPref(std::string key) {
    
    NSString *preferencePlist = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/com.rA9.LeetDownPreferences.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:preferencePlist];
    return dict[key];
}
```

The issue is, when I create a plistModifier object and call it's methods, the compiler throws the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "plistModifier<int>::modifyPref(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int)", referenced from: -[SettingsVC debuggingToggle:] in SettingsVC.o`

This is how I call the methods of the object in `SettingsVC.mm` file:

```objectivec
#import "SettingsVC.h"
#include "plistModifier.h"

plistModifier<int> plistObject;

- (IBAction)debuggingToggle:(id)sender {
    
    plistObject.modifyPref("DebugEnabled", _debugToggle.state);
}
```

I have tried using the same templated class in an empty C++ project, and it didn't give me any errors. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure that plistModifier.mm is added to the app target? Check "target membership" in file inspector (right panel). It must match with SettingsVC.mm.

Comment: Yes, it is added. I ended up converting the templated class to a normal C++ class and treating all of the values inside the plist file as NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to split template declaration (.h) and definition (.mm/.cpp).
You have to keep the template methods implementation in the .h file.

[Refer to this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115735/1009546)

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

But since your implementation is not using the generic type `type` properties, you could split it by implementing this in terms of [`id` type](http://dobegin.com/objc-id-type/) in .mm, and then adding a templated wrapper in .h file:

```
// .mm

void plistModifierImpl::modifyPref(std::string key, id val) {    
    NSString *preferencePlist = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/com.rA9.LeetDownPreferences.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:preferencePlist];
    [dict setValue:val forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:val]];
    [dict writeToFile:preferencePlist atomically:YES];    
}
```

```
// .h

class plistModifierImpl; // define this in .mm

template <class type>
class plistModifier {
    // private loosely-typed implementation
    std::unique_ptr<plistModifierImpl> p_impl;

public:
    // public strongly-typed wrapper
    void modifyPref(std::string key, type value) {
        p_impl->modifyPref(key, value);
    }
    ...
}
```

This works as long as `type` can be implicitly casted to `id`, which is true for NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray and NSDictionary.

If you need to support primitive types like `int`, you need to specialize the template with an adjusted implementation.