# Unable to build If I declare virtual function in the child class in the .cpp file instead of the header file

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
template<typename T>
class GameDatabase {
public:
    GameDatabase(PreparedStatement<T>* preparedStatement,GameDatabaseFlags gdf)
    {
        _preparedStatement = preparedStatement;
        _gameObjectDatabaseFlag = gdf;
    }
    GameDatabaseFlags _gameObjectDatabaseFlag;
    virtual void MapGameDatabaseContainer(GameDatabaseContainer gameDatabaseContainer) = 0;
protected:
    uint32_t versionId;
    PreparedStatement<T>* _preparedStatement;
};
```

Than I have my derived class `GameObjectsDatabase.h`:

```
template<typename T>
class GameObjectsDatabase : public GameDatabase<T> {
public:
     GameObjectsDatabase(PreparedStatement<T>* preparedStatement,GameDatabaseFlags gdf) : GameDatabase<T>(preparedStatement, gdf) {}
     void MapGameDatabaseContainer(GameDatabaseContainer gameDatabaseContainer);


};

template<typename T>
void GameObjectsDatabase<T>::MapGameDatabaseContainer(GameDatabaseContainer gameDatabaseContainer) {

}
```

As you can see the declaration of `MapGameDatabaseContainer` is made in the header file and the program compiles.

If I take this:

```
template<typename T>
void GameObjectsDatabase<T>::MapGameDatabaseContainer(GameDatabaseContainer gameDatabaseContainer) {

}
```

Out of `GameObjectsDatabase.h` and place it in `GameObjectsDatabase.cpp` I get this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

```
"__ZN19GameObjectsDatabaseI23WorldDatabaseConnectionE24MapGameDatabaseContainerE21GameDatabaseContainer", referenced from:
      __ZTV19GameObjectsDatabaseI23WorldDatabaseConnectionE in GameDatabaseLoader.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [bin/lib/libCommon.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [WorldServer] Error 2
```

Why is that? Why I can't declare it outside of the header file ?

Comment: [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115735) or [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021)

Comment: How do you think the compiler could compile that code? It doesn't know what `T` is.