# Implementing member functions of a class template

Tags: c++, class, templates

Ok, I think I'm missing something fundamental with templates.

I have a class of ephemeris data, that was originally defined as:

```
class EphemerisPoint;
class Ephemeris
{
 private:
    vector<EphemerisPoint> data;

 public:
    StateVector interpolate(double time);
};
```

where interpolate is defined in the cc file:

```
StateVector Ephemeris::interpolate(double time)
{
...
}
```

I have a use case where I'd like to replace vector<> with boost::circular_buffer<>

So I make it a class template:

```
class EphemerisPoint;
template <class T> class Ephemeris
{
 private:
    T data;

 public:
    StateVector interpolate(double time);
};
```

and the implementation of interpolate():

```
template<class T> StateVector Ephemeris<T>::interpolate(double time)
{
...
}
```

This is all compiled into a library.

But when I use it:

```
Ephemeris<boost::circular_buffer<EphemerisPoint> > ephem;

ephem.interpolate(10.0);
```

It compiles fine - but when linking against the library, I get a message like this:

```
undefined reference to `Ephemeris<boost::circular_buffer<EphemerisPoint, std::allocator<EphemerisPoint> > >::propagate(double)'
```

And if I run the library through nm, I see that there is no Ephemeris::interpolate in the library??

However, if somewhere else in this large library, I instantiate and use an Ephemerisboost::circular_buffer<EphemerisPoint > object, then the appropriate Ephemeris::interpolate() function for boost::circular_buffer will exist in the library and I can use it in programs linked against it.

But if I try to instantiate the old vector based one, that again won't link.

Do I have to instantiate a version of Ephemeris inside the library with every template type I intend to use?  This doesn't seem to align with how I thought templates worked.

gcc 4.8.5, using -std=gnu++11 on CentOS 7 FWIW

Comment: Implementation of template (member) function should be within the class within the header file. And you can't both have an untemplated class and templated class with the same name

Comment: Wow - Ok, I mean I guess I could.  But this is a class with many large methods (parsers for various file formats, among other things) - the source file almost 10K lines.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Within the header file yes.  Within the class, please no.  Keep it organized.  via #include of helper header files, if that helps with organization.

Comment: @CoAstroGeek -- The `<algorithm>` header in Visual C++ is almost 10K lines, so this is not strange.

Comment: Them's the breaks. The compiler needs to see the actual implementation at the point the template is used and its parameters become known.

Answer (score -1):

Ok comments above got me oriented to an answer that won't involve moving 10K lines of code into my header file.

[How can I avoid linker errors with my template functions?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl)

I think this will also let me restrict the allowable template classes to vector and boost::circular_buffer

Off to try it - this is probably a duplicate of numerous other questions, like this: [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) so feel free to close it if you like.

Comment: A couple usage notes: Avoid writing answers that are essentially "Do this: <link to existing answer>". Instead propose the existing answer as a duplicate. Don't make an answer until AFTER you've tested that the solution works. If it doesn't you may find it's been downvoted to the bottom of the sea (and maybe even deleted if the answer's so bad that it's dangerous) by the time you find out and come back to fix it. Unlike with questions, there's a built-in incentive for people to return and reassess improved answers, but if the downvoter isn't aware the answer was updated...