# Ambiguity resolution when making a C++ parser

Tags: c++, parsing, lalr

I wrote a LALR(1) parser for C++17. I found **156** ambiguities, some of them I can resolve it according to standard but the others I can't.

For example:
Shift-Reduce conflict occurs while parsing "*operator+ < ......*" when a **less-than** is encountered:

We may parse it as:

(1)

*template-id -> operator-function-id  **·** < ...... >*

or:

(2)

*unqualified-id -> operator-function-id  **·***
where (1) need shifting but (2) need reducing.

However, the standard have:

*After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name or that an operator-function-id or a literaloperator-id refers to a set of overloaded functions any member of which is a function template, if this is followed by a <, the < is always taken as the delimiter of a template-argument-list and never as the less-than operator. When parsing a template-argument-list, the first non-nested >137 is taken as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator.*

So we choose to shift.

Unfortunately, there are many ambiguities I can't find the resolution. Here I list some of them(Some of them can clearly make choice but I just can't find the proof):

1. Are there some portion in standard that indicates "shifting" is the default choice when ambiguity occurs?

**Declarator**

(1)when a noptr-declarator is parsed and a left-paren is encountered, I should reduce it according to:

*ptr-declarator -> noptr-declarator  **·***

or shift the left-paren to satisfy:

*declarator -> noptr-declarator **·** parameters-and-qualifiers*

*parameters-and-qualifiers ->  **·** left-paren parameter-declaration-clause right-paren......*

(2)when a declarator-id is parsed and a left-bracket is encountered, I should reduce it according to:

*noptr-declarator -> declarator-id  **·*** 
*noptr-declarator -> noptr-declarator **·** \left-bracket ?constant-expression \right-bracket ?attribute-specifier-seq*

or shift the left-square to satisfy:

*noptr-declarator -> declarator-id ·attribute-specifier-seq*

(attribute-specifier-seq is [[.......]])

Comment: Last time I looked, which was in the 1990s, the C++ grammar had 53 shift-reduce conflicts and, if I am not mistaken, some reduce-reduce conflicts as well.

Comment: Nowhere does the C++ standard say that the grammar is a LARL(1) grammar. Nor does it describe how you are meant to implement a parser.

Comment: It's well known that the grammar *can't* be parsed a la LALR, so what do you expect, or want?

Answer (score 6):

Following up on TonyD's comment:  See [Why can't C++ be parsed with a LR(1) parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-cant-c-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737)

In some places, you essentially have to keep the ambiguity produced by parsing, and resolve it by doing name resolution, *or* equivalently, you have to tangle name resolution into the parsing process.  In either case, you have to interpret the standard to determine how the ambiguities should be resolved, and yes, that's a very difficult task.

Then you get to find out what the compilers *really* do; both GCC and MS have lots of extensions and variations from the standard, both in terms of syntax and semantic interpretations (these produce programs that produce different results under different compilers).   Lastly, you get to find what abominations are in the system header files; these are hacks that added by the compiler folks to make their lives convenient, and are very badly documented, if at all.

Answer (score -1):

C++ is [Turing Complete to parse](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c%2B%2B/turing.pdf).

Very relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794015/what-do-people-mean-when-they-say-c-has-undecidable-grammar).