# Higher-kinded Types with C++

Tags: c++, templates, haskell, higher-kinded-types

This question is for the people who know both Haskell (or any other functional language that supports Higher-kinded Types) and C++...

Is it possible to model higher kinded types using C++ templates? If yes, then how?

**EDIT :**

From [this](http://www.blumenfeld-maso.com/2010/01/what-does-monad-mean-by-tony-morris/) presentation by Tony Morris:

**Higher-order Polymorphism :**

- Languages such as Java and C# have
  first-order polymorphism because they
  allow us to abstract on types. e.g.
  `List<A>` can have a `reverse` function
  that works on any element type (the
  `A`).
- More practical programming languages
  and type systems allow us to
  abstract on type constructors as
  well.
- This feature is called higher-order
  (or higher-kinded) polymorphism.

**Example :**

Pseudo-Java with an invented notation for higher-order polymorphism

```
interface Transformer<X, Y> {
  Y transform(X x);
}

interface Monad<M> { // M :: * -> *
  <A> M<A> pure(A a);
  <A, B> M<B> bind(Transformer<A, M<B>> t, M<A> a);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of your goal. For us don't-know-functional-idioms-very-well types that would help.

Comment: @GMan: I could give an example, but I'm well aware it will hardly mean anything except for the people who know it already. So I didn't bother to include an example.

Comment: @Venkat: I mean a goal, what's your bigger picture? You want a higher-kinded type for: __________. Also, a very simple example with comments would still be better than nothing. :)

Comment: I think an over-arching goal would still be very helpful for everyone.

Comment: @Venkat: Excellent thanks. Now that I get it...oh wait, already been answered. :)

Comment: Isn't this what the Boost library does?

Comment: [C++ templates are turing complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189172/c-templates-turing-complete)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Template-template parameters?

```
template <template <typename> class m>
struct Monad {
    template <typename a>
    static m<a> mreturn(const a&);
    
    template <typename a, typename b>
    static m<b> mbind(const m<a>&, m<b>(*)(const a&));
};

template <typename a>
struct Maybe {
    bool isNothing;
    a value;
};

template <>
struct Monad<Maybe> {
    template <typename a>
    static Maybe<a> mreturn(const a& v) {
        Maybe<a> x;
        x.isNothing = false;
        x.value = v;
        return x;
    }
    
    template <typename a, typename b>
    static Maybe<b> mbind(const Maybe<a>& action, Maybe<b>(*function)(const a&)) {
        if (action.isNothing)
            return Maybe<b>{true, b{}};
        else
            return function(action.value);
    }
};
```

Comment: So template parameters can be templates themselves? Great! I didn't know that! Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: I other words: the template system in C++ being (accidentally) Turing Complete it's quite incredible what you can do with it :)

Comment: what's the highest rank of higher order types that can be constructed with this tho? is `template <template <template ...> > >` allowed?

Comment: @ErikAllik There's no natural limitation. You could do `template <template <template <template <...> class> class> class m>`.

Comment: what I'm more interested in, is how this higher-kinded struct is used... Could I get you to add an example that uses `mbind` in conjunction with `Maybe` and `Monad<Maybe>`?

Answer (score 3):

Isn't usually a normal template already a higher-kinded type? For example `std::vector` takes a type parameter to create an actual type like `std::vector<int>`, so it has kind `* -> *`.

Comment: The question is really about polymorphism over higher-kinded types, i.e. having *variables* with higher kinds.

Comment: @Ganesh: Yeah, by now it is. In the beginning it just asked if there were types of higher kinds, so I didn't mention templates as template parameters to not complicate things necessarily.