# How to avoid gcc crash due to lack of memory

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++

I keep crashing gcc (due to lack of memory) when trying to compile a class which is using many function templates defined in the corresponding .h file for my class. I have 6.4GB of memory available when I start compilation of that cpp file:

```
$ free -mh
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           9.7G        3.1G        6.5G        260K        212M        6.4G
    Swap:          947M        887M         59M
```

Here's details of gcc:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
```

Here's the memory situation right before the crash while compiling that file:

```
$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.7G        9.6G        113M        352K         58M        816K
Swap:          947M        947M          0B
```

And the crash details:

```
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
main.dir/build.make:127: recipe for target 'myclass.cpp.o' failed
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this (besides removing the templates)? I personally think 6.4GB should be enough memory to compile a .cpp file regardless of how complicated the file. Am I wrong here in this thinking?

EDIT. Here's the function prototypes in the .hpp:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

template<typename MapTypeT, typename KeyTypeT, typename ValueTypeT>
ObjectPtr InitMap(KeyTypeT key, ValueTypeT value, std::list<std::pair<ObjectPtr, ObjectPtr>> keyValuePairs); 
template<typename KeyTypeT, typename ValueTypeT>

ObjectPtr ConstructMap(KeyTypeT key, ValueTypeT value, std::list<std::pair<ObjectPtr, ObjectPtr>> keyValuePairs); // calls InitMap<std::unordered_map> and InitMap<std::map>

template<typename KeyTypeT>
ObjectPtr DeduceValue(KeyTypeT key, const ObjectPtr &anyValue, const std::list<std::pair<ObjectPtr, ObjectPtr>> &keyValuePairs); // calls ConstructMap<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT> 

ObjectPtr CreateMap(std::list<std::pair<ObjectPtr, ObjectPtr>> keyValuePairs); // calls DeduceValue<KeyTypeT>
```

EDIT2.

Here's proof that gcc is actually using 6GB for compilation:

```
Tasks: 295 total,   4 running, 223 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 57.0 us,  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 10208840 total,   138780 free,  9850648 used,   219412 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   969960 total,       28 free,   969932 used.   104132 avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
 91917 mfonnem+  20   0 6381472 6.029g  14936 R  99.3 61.9   2:50.04 cc1plus    
 90603 mfonnem+  20   0 5300888 1.243g  16796 S   8.6 12.8   5:42.14 java
```

EDIT 3. I increased the swap memory to 8GB and now gcc uses just under 8GB while trying to compile that file:

```
top - 00:13:27 up  5:25,  1 user,  load average: 2.55, 2.02, 1.92
Tasks: 298 total,   3 running, 226 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.9 us, 16.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 13.4 id, 42.9 wa,  0.0 hi, 23.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 10208832 total,   111252 free, 10015484 used,    82096 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  3069856 free,  5318748 used.     7256 avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
 25578   20   0 9071708 7.498g    412 R  27.2 77.0   5:27.26 cc1plus
```

Eventually, it reports:

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
     }
     ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

EDIT4. Compilation in clang++ is possible.

Comment: We need to see the templates.

Comment: Reminder:  Just because your maching has 6.4GB, doesn't mean that `g++` gets to use it all.  The memory is shared amongst all the running programs and services.

Comment: Are your templates recursively defined and, if so, does the recursion terminate correctly?

Comment: "regardless of how complicated the file. " So you think everything should be able to compile in O(1) memory?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sort of?   Each process gets its own process space.   Also, presumably his computer doesn't actually have 6.4GB of RAM - it seems far more likely that's the amount free before he started.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I've included the exact function prototypes being used.

Comment: @markf78 Those templates actually look pretty benign. I can't imagine they would result in any dramatic memory consumption.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews True, but the computer is essentially idle besides the compilation. I realize that it is technically not true. I will try to include the results from top.

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a compiler bug. As the error message said, report it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've added the prototypes for the templates.

Comment: @G.M. no they are not defined recursively

Comment: You could increase your swap-memory.

Comment: @xaxxon this was not meant as an attack on gcc... but 6GB is a lot of memory breing used to compile 1 object file.

Comment: compilers only ever make one object file at a time so i don’t see how that’s relevant.

Comment: Voting to close because there’s no [mcve]

Comment: You certainly don't need -when using `g++`- the JVM (`java`) which apparently consumes a lot of resources on your system

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I wonder if the JVM is for CLion?

Comment: gcc has a default template recursion limit. I'd expect you'd bump into that before ice'ing the compiler by running out of memory.

Answer (score 5):

> I personally think 6.4GB should be enough memory to compile a .cpp file regardless of how complicated the file. Am I wrong here in this thinking?

Yes. C++ templates happen to be "accidentally" Turing-complete (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189172/841108) and read  Todd L. Veldhuizen  [*C++ Templates are Turing Complete*](http://osl.iu.edu/~tveldhui/papers/2003/turing.ps) paper).

So **you are wrong**. Pathological C++ programs can take an arbitrary (or even infinite) amount of time and memory to be compiled (and coding such pathological C++ programs is quite easy).

In other words, C++ program writers should use templates with great care and parsimony. It is quite easy to write an explosive template (with [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) at template expansion time). When you code templates, you need to convince yourself (and ideally, to prove) that their expansion takes linear (or bounded, or at least reasonable) time and space so you should estimate the time and space [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) of the template expansion.

BTW 8 gigabytes of RAM is not a lot today. Consider buying more RAM, increasing your swap space, closing every non-essential applications ([IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s, word processors, web browsers, JVMs, ...), disabling debugging information, decreasing optimization level, when compiling that stuff (and compile it on the command line). Perhaps upgrading to [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) might help also. Try perhaps also [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

And you could have bugs in your templates (e.g. improper or "infinite" recursive or excessive expansion).

You may want to use [GCC C++ options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) like `-ftemplate-depth` (to catch template excessive depth).

Comment: Disabling debug does a lot more for decreasing memory usage than removing optimizations.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch This was not meant as an attack on gcc. I realize compilation is difficult as I've written non-production level compilers before. But, 6GB for a single object file just seems like a lot of memory to me. Btw, the templates are not recursively calling themselves.

Comment: Please don’t comment on your belief of what is going on.  Instead post an [mcve]

Comment: @xaxxon it's not a belief I posted evidence that gcc is using 6GB of memory at the time of the crash. please see the output from top.

Comment: You did not yet post any [MCVE]. We need it

Comment: @markf78 the true beauty of the MCVE is you'll probably get it half done, see the problem, give yourself a slap, and then fix the problem yourself. A good MCVE can be brutal and time-consuming, but damn are they effective.

Comment: @xaxxon You can delete the question if you like; I don't think I have the privileges to do it myself. btw, I am now able to compile in clang but not gcc. Unable to duplicate In a MCV though.

Answer (score 1):

I have normally found that adding more swap space generally fixes issues with GCC. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space) for how to add swapspace -- Although the price you pay is a compile/link times that can take hours.
As for why, I suspect the "mangling rules" for templates is the killer factor, although it's hard prove. Dumping the symbols (using -Q flag) might help you understand better.

*Ideas for fixing the build*

- You might find that moving symbols into an anonymous namespace speeds things up (removes them from the exported symbols)
- You also might find a [UnityBuild](https://onqtam.com/programming/2018-07-07-unity-builds/) approach helps, by doing more work while the symbols are created.

Sorry for not being more help, but it might you give you ideas. If you find anything interesting with "-Q", please post the results.