# How are Java generics different from C++ templates? Why can't I use int as a parameter?

Tags: java, c++, generics, c++-templates

I am trying to create

```
ArrayList<int> myList = new ArrayList<int>();
```

in Java but that does not work.

Can someone explain why `int` as type parameter does not work?
Using `Integer` class for `int` primitive works, but can someone explain why `int` is not accepted?

Java version 1.6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Java generics are so different from C++ templates that I am not going to try to list the differences here. (See [What are the differences between “generic” types in C++ and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java) for more details.)

In this particular case, the problem is that you cannot use primitives as generic type parameters (see [JLS §4.5.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.5.1): "Type arguments may be either reference types or wildcards.").

However, due to autoboxing, you can do things like:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(3); // 3 is autoboxed into Integer.valueOf(3)
```

So that removes some of the pain. It definitely hurts runtime efficiency, though.

Comment: Not much. I once migrated a fairly big bunch of core code to use custom "primitivized" collections/maps expecting to see a performance improvement. There was basically no measurable difference.

Answer (score 28):

The reason that `int` doesn't work, is that you cannot use primitive types as generic parameters in Java.

As to your actual question, how C++ templates are different from Java generics, the answer is that they're really, really different. The languages essentially apply completely different approaches to implementing a **similar** end effect.

Java tends to focus on the definition of the generic.  That is, the validity of the generic definition is checked by only considering the code in the generic. If parameters are not properly constrained, certain actions cannot be performed on them. The actual type it's eventually invoked with, is not considered.

C++ is the opposite. Only minimal verification is done on the template itself. It really only needs to be parsable to be considered valid. The actual correctness of the definition is done at the place in which the template is used.

Comment: +1 for a gallant attempt to explain the difference :-) (although I might take issue with the minimal verification of C++ templates - any code not depending on the template parameters is fully checked)

Comment: Also, just so people know, the C++ community has put much effort into addressing the concerns about minimal verification of dependent template code (especially when it leads to cryptic error messages). C++0x will have templates that can be constrained by 'Concepts' and their definition will be fully verified when the definition is first encountered (error messages will make much more sense).  C++0x will also have unconstrained templates of course (which have their own advantages :).

Comment: @Faisal:  To keep this up to date, I should probably mention that since your comment "concepts" have been removed from C++0x (now probably C++0B).  This was, shall we say, not a universally popular decision.

Comment: To keep it up to date again, they were planned to be included in C++17 but this was not accepted **again**. They are included as a compiler extension in GCC from version 6 onwards.

Answer (score 12):

The main difference is in way they are implemented, but their names accurately describe their implementation.

Templates behave like templates. So, if you write:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T s)
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

...
int x = 0;
f(x);
...
```

Compiler applies the template, so in the end compiler treats the code like:

```
void f_generated_with_int(int s)
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

...
int x = 0;
f_generated_with_int(x);
...
```

So, for each type which is used to call `f` a new code is "generated".

On the other hand, generics is only typechecked, but then all type information is erased. So, if you write:

```
class X<T> {
    private T x;

    public T getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(T x) { this.x = x; }
}

...
Foo foo = new Foo();
X<Foo> x = new X<>();
x.setX(foo);
foo = x.getX();
...
```

Java compiles it like:

```
class X {
    private Object x;

    public Object getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(Object x) { this.x = x; }
}

...
Foo foo = new Foo();
X x = new X();
x.setX(foo);
foo = (Foo)x.getX();
...
```

In the end:

- templates require instantiation of each call to templated function (in compilation of each .cpp file), so templates are slower to compile
- with generics you can't use primitives, because they are not `Object`, so generics is less versatile

Answer (score 11):

They are very different concepts, which can be used to perform some, but not all of the same tasks. As said in the other responses, it would take a quite a bit to go over all the differences, but here's what I see as the broad strokes.

Generics allow for runtime polymorphic containers through a single instantiation of a generic container. In Java, all the (non-primitive) objects are references, and all references are the same size (and have some of the same interface), and so can be handled by the bytecode. However, a necessary implication of having only instantiation of byte code is type eraser; you can't tell which class the container was instantiated with. This wouldn't work in c++ because of a fundamentally different object model, where objects aren't always references.

Templates allow for compile time polymorphic containers through multiple instantiations (as well as template metaprogramming by providing a (currently weakly typed) language over the c++ type system.). This allows for specializations for given types, the downside being potential "code bloat" from needing more than one compiled instantiation.

Templates are more powerful than generics; the former is effectively another language embedded within c++, while to the best of my knowledge, the latter is useful only in containers

Comment: [Bolts Tasks](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android) is an interesting example of Generics being useful outside of containers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use primitives as type parameters in Java.  Java's generics worth through type erasure, meaning that the compiler checks that you're using the types as you've defined them, but upon compilation, everything is treated as an Object.  Since int and other primitives aren't Objects, they can't be used.  Instead, use Integer.

Answer (score 3):

that's because int is a primitive, it is a [known issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4487555).

If you really wanted to, you can subclass/write your own collection that can do that.

Comment: @z Link says `This bug is not available`

Answer (score 1):

You could try TIntArraList from GNU Trove which will act like an ArrayList of int values.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, Java objects are somewhat equivalent to pointers in C++.

Java does garbage collection because those dynamic obejcts will be "unseen" (stop being pointed) at some point and then a space cleaning is needed.

`int` is recognized as a primitive type so that makes impossible to return `null` and that's the reason why Java generics cannot accept primitve types. To indicate that an element isn't stored inside a Java container as `Map`, `Set`, `List`, a method will return `null`. Then what are you going to return if you can't return `null` ?

For `std::array`, static and dynamic arrays, C++ forces you to define a default constructor, it's because as C++ arrays are arrays of types instead of arrays of pointers as in Java. You have to indicate which default value (`null` value in Java) is going to take the objects in such structure.

Think about it, in Java any object in an array is `null` by default, in C++ it isn't unleast you declare an array of pointers and set all those at `0x0` or (preferable) as `nullptr`.