# Multilevel map in Java

Tags: java, tree

What is the best way in Java to keep values ("o") in a tree structure like this:

```
                    obj1                 
                     /\
                    /  \
                   /    \
              obj2        obj3
              /\            /\
             /  \          /  \
            /    \        /    \
          obj4  obj5    obj6   obj7
          /\     /\     /\      /\
         /  \   /  \   /  \    /  \
        o8   oN...
```

It looks like a tree, but I don't need arbitrary depth. I rather need strong datatyping and predefined good looking methods for working with final structure.

I need to be able to get some kind of list of values by keys - exactly like on my picture. In other words, structure should **not** become planar in any way.

I need `.get(obj3)` to return `{obj6, obj7}, .get(obj1) - {obj2, obj3}`.

For now I use Map for that, but inflating such map is ugly, because I need to check each level of the structure. Looks like that (**data** is the map):

```
if(data.get(somedouble) == null) {
    Map<Integer, Data> inm = new TreeMap<>();
    inm.put(someint, obj);
    Map<Double, Map<Integer, Data>> m = new TreeMap<>();
    m.put(somedouble2, inm);
    data.put(somedouble, m);
}
else {
    if(data.get(somedouble).get(somedouble2) == null) {
        Map<Integer, Data> inm = new TreeMap<>();
        inm.put(someint, obj);
        data.get(somedouble).put(somedouble2, inm);
    }
    else
        data.get(somedouble).get(somedouble2).put(someint, obj);
}
```

Performance in not an issue, but code beauty is.

Comment: Yes, it will simplify using such map, but how can it help me to get rid of verbose multilevel checks on creation?

Comment: duffymo, I thought about it (actually, I just need some special hashing and equality function), but it looks like too much work for such simple task.

Comment: It's not obvious what you mean by "planar". Can you restate?

Comment: I'm wondering how many times the specification will change again.

Comment: I'm going to stop for now. Sorry again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use your specific key:

```
class MyKey {
    Double beta;
    Double yaw;
    int minute;

    public int hashCode() {
        /* Returns hash code from a combination of hash of the key members. */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        /* Returns true if obj is a MyKey with same members. */
    }
}
```

And then simply:

```
data.put(myKey, obj);
```

This way the "multi-level checks" are all hidden in `MyKey.equals()`. It keeps the client code clean and the key complexity is in a safe place.

#### Edit after requirement changes:

If on top of this, you want to be able to have a map from your double `beta` to your objects, then I would still keep the thing planar like that.

What you actually want is to have multiple "indexes" for your data, like in a database, so you can query for objects with same "beta" or "yaw". For that the best way is to use several Map (actually Multimap), one for each of your "indexes".

Using [Guava's Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html):

```
ListMultimap<Double, Data> mapForBeta;
ListMultimap<Double, Data> mapForYaw;
```

You can put all the multimap and the `Map<MyKey, Data>` in your a specific class. Actually the best way would be to subclass `Map<MyKey, Data>`:

```
public class MyMap extends HashMap<MyKey, Data> {

    ListMultimap<Double, Data> mapForBeta;
    ListMultimap<Double, Data> mapForYaw;


    public Data put(MyKey key, Data value) {
        super.put(key, value);
        mapForBeta.add(key.beta, value);
        mapForYaw.add(key.yaw, value);
    };

    public List<Data> getFromBeta(Double beta) {
        return mapForBeta.get(beta);
    }

    public List<Data> getFromYaw(Double yaw) {
        return mapForYaw.get(yaw);
    }
}
```

#### New Edit with better solution:

Actually, it got me thinking, and I realized that you are really having a problem with default values for your maps, and that's why your code is a bit messy.

You can solve this with a Default Map using a generator to create underlying maps:

```
public class DefaultMap<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {

    static abstract class Generator<V>{
        abstract V create();
    }

    final Generator<V> generator;


    DefaultMap(Generator<V> generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        V val = super.get(key);
        if (val == null) {
            val = generator.create();

            put((K)key, val);
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

Now you can have your utility tree class to store all your data :

```
public class MyTree {
  private final Map<Double, Map<Double, Map<Integer, Data>>> data;

  public MyTree() {
    data = new DefaultMap<>(new Generator<Map<Double, Map<Integer, Data>>>() {
      @Override
      Map<Double, Map<Integer, Data>> create() {
        return new DefaultMap<>(new Generator<Map<Integer, Data>>() {

          @Override
          Map<Integer, Data> create() {
            return new TreeMap<>();
          }

        });
      }
    });
  }

  void add(MyKey d, Data obj) {
    data.get(d.beta).get(d.yaw).put(d.minute, obj);
  }
}
```

Now you can access your data with data.get(beta).get(yaw) and you don't have spaghetti code to store your values.

Comment: I'm afraid the specification is going to change, based on the comment to my answer, "But how would I get all values, by double d1?"

Comment: Done. The specification has changed.

Comment: I see. Well, I may be a bit stubborn, but with a bit of addition, I think my solution is still the best one. :)

Comment: And what about getByYaw and Beta? Like this: data.get(double1).get(double2).get(int)

Comment: Well, you can always have another YawBetaKey and have another Multimap to store the relation. But I see your point. I like my stuff because you can make nicely named methods like getFromBetaAndYaw() and this kind of things.

Comment: See my new edit with a new solution. What do you think about that?

Comment: Your solution is really flexible and does not requires much coding - that's perfectly fits my case. I don't need tree with arbitrary depth, I rather need strong data typing for all the Structure - one more advantage of using multiple indexes. Thanks for an idea, I used it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

What about a binary tree?

*Node.java*

```
public class Node {

    private Node leftChild;
    private Node rightChild;

    public Node(Node leftChild, Node rightChild) {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
        this.rightChild = rightChild;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return this instanceof Leaf;
    }

}
```

*Leaf.java*

```
public class Leaf extends Node {

    private Data data;

    public Leaf(Data data) {
        super(null, null);
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

For example, if you want to build to following tree:

```
         root
          /\
         /  \
        /    \
   node1     node2
   /\           /\
  /  \         /  \
leaf1 leaf2  leaf3 leaf4
```

Use:

```
Leaf leaf1 = new Leaf(new Data());
Leaf leaf2 = new Leaf(new Data());
Leaf leaf3 = new Leaf(new Data());
Leaf leaf4 = new Leaf(new Data());

Node node1 = new Node(leaf1, leaf2);
Node node2 = new Node(leaf3, leaf4);

Node root = new Node(node1, node2);
```

Comment: "data" is a kind of Map, not binary tree.