# What does Object<String> signify in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java but not to programming (I normally code in Ruby). One thing I've seen in Java code examples is the use of <> instead of () to pass params to an object. Below is a code example (taken from a Google Web Toolkit tutorial):

```
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    String token = event.getValue();

    // depending on the value of the token, do whatever you need
    ...
}
```

Does it have to do with casting or is it something else? Can someone explain to me what this signifies or is used for? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [type parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) for a generic class. Basically, a `ValueChangeEvent<String>` represents an event that notified listeners that a value has changed, and in this case the value is of type `String`.

It's easier to understand with the standard example in the collections framework:

A `List<String>` is a `List` that contains `String` objects. The advantage over just using the "raw type" `List` is that the compiler will refuse code that puts anything except `String` objects into a `List<String>`, and allow objects retrieved from it to be used as `String` without casting.

Basically, generics allow cleaner code and improve the overall type safety of Java code by making it unnecessary in many cases to work with the `Object` type and cast values from it.

Answer (score 3):

It is called generics, or generic parameters. They allow a method or object to operate on multiple types of data while maintaining type safety. One common use is to specify what the type of the objects stored in a collection is.

See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) on the subject for more information.

Comment: ... but as wiki will tell you as well, generics in Java aren't quite as type safe because of the goddamn type erasure.

Comment: They offer much better type safety than pre-generics java where you had to return an `Object` and trust yourself to cast it properly, offering no compile time checking. Yes, type erasure sucks balls some times (especially with arrays), but it is *much* better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Reese has the right answer. Here are some links for you:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf (PDF)

Answer (score 1):

The use of angle brackets usually signify generic programming methods, which is a style of programming where types are not declared initially, making code much more re-usable.

For example:

```
// Declare the generic class
public class GenericList<T>
{
    void Add(T input) { }
}
class TestGenericList
{
    private class ExampleClass { }
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a list of type int
        GenericList<int> list1 = new GenericList<int>();

        // Declare a list of type string
        GenericList<string> list2 = new GenericList<string>();

        // Declare a list of type ExampleClass
        GenericList<ExampleClass> list3 = new GenericList<ExampleClass>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<>` signify generics. Have a look at [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html). For instance, `List<String>` is a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) in java. They are similar to [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(programming)) in C++.

They basically let you implement a generic class for any type and then when you initialise a variable of this class you specify what type (e.g. String, int, double, etc.) it applies its stuff to. A good example is in an ArrayList, what type should the container store? The implementation is the same, only the type differs.

Comment: Saying that they are similar to templates in C++ would be wrong IMO since templates fundamentally work at a very different level when compared to generics. Moar reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java/498329#498329

Answer (score 0):

It's usually used so you can trust that an element of a collection/list is a certain type.

For example,

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList();
a.add("Test");

myFunctionWhichAcceptsString(a.get(0));
```

If *myFunctionWhichAcceptsString* only accepted a String as the parameter, you wouldn't be able to use a normal ArrayList without casting the result as a String, since it stores an Object and Object ≠ String. By doing it this way you're saying that the list has to be only Strings. You can do this for any type of object.