# java template generic type

Tags: java, c++, generics

I am newbie to java. But I used c++ a lot. I got a class written in c++. Now I need to rewrite the class in java. I got confused about the generic types.

My c++ class is something like this:

```
//Form, Cmpt are of class type. nCmpt is a integer

template <class Form, class Cmpt, int nCmpt>
class VectorSpace
{
public:
   //component array
   Cmpt v[nCmpt];
   //constructors
   VectorSpace();
   VectorSpace(const VectorSpace<Form,Cmpt,nCmpt>& m_v);
   .....
   .....
};
```

I tried to rewrite it in java, I got problems:

```
public class VectorSpace<Form, Cmpt, nCmpt>
{
    public Cmpt v[];
    public VectorSpace()
    {
        v = new Cmpt[nCmpt];
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

I got errors:

**Can't create a generic array of Cmpt.

nCmpt cannot be resolved to a variable.**

Can anyone help this out? How can I use template in java to achieve the same functionality as it was in c++? (I don't want to define an integer variable inside class and use it as an argument in the constructor of my java version).

Thank you.

Comment: Java generic parameters can only be types.

Comment: Use `Object v[]`. It's not generic, and you need casting in places.

Comment: This sounds like a flippant answer, but as someone who was once in your shoes (long ago :) ), my recommendation would be to try to forget C++ templates altogether and just learn Java as if they're a new thing. Obviously the motivations behind the two are very similar, but the implementations _and the patterns they imply_ are different enough that it's probably easier to learn them as separate constructs, than it is to try to "translate" templates to generics.

Answer (score 2):

C++ templates are very different from Java generics, [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java). Java Doesn't allow the construction generic arrays because of type erasure . You can create the array as array of objects and cast to `Cmpt[]` afterwards

```
// we can't pass values as type-parameter in Java 
public VectorSpace(int nCmpt){ 
   v = (Cmpt[])new Object[nCmpt];
}
```

This code however is dodgy and you better avoid arrays with generics and  use a `List` instead. [Prefer Lists To Arrays](http://efectivejava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/item-25-prefer-lists-to-arrays.html)

```
private List<Cmpt> v;

public VectorSpace()
{
    v = new ArrayList<Cmpt>();
}
```

I don't recommend you learning Java or any language by direct translation. Pick a book or an online tutorial and teach yourself the language.

Comment: For your first answer, the error is still there: nCmpt cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `(Cmpt[])new Object[nCmpt];` This isn't an immediately good idea for the OP's case because `v` is public. (Arrays created this way shouldn't be exposed.)

Comment: @Radiodef of course, this why I mentioned List, v should be private anyways

Comment: You cannot cast an `Object[]` to a `<? extends Object>[]`. It's a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ templates don't directly translate to Java generics:

- `nCmpt` should be just a member variable.
- Java arrays and generics don't mix very well.  Most of the time, you are better off using `ArrayList`.
- As https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html states:

> **By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters.** This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>   
>   With all that, your class becomes:

```
class VectorSpace<F, C> {

    private final List<C> v;
    private final int nCmpt;

    public VectorSpace(int nCmpt) {
        this.nCmpt = nCmpt;
        this.v = new ArrayList<>(nCmpt);
    }
}
```

---

```
VectorSpace<String, Integer> vc = new VectorSpace<>(3);
```