# Priority queue comparing - java vs c++

Tags: java, c++, priority-queue

I have no idea how to use priority queue in java just like in C++.
In c++ we can make it like this:

```
priority_queue<object*, vector<object*>, compareClass>
```

So when we have class like this:

```
class Foo{
public:
    int number1;
    int number2
    Foo(){};
};
```

We can use two different queues to compare in them by 2 different ideas just by making two compareClasses.

In java I got problem cause when I make queue like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Foo> pq = new PriorityQueue<Foo>();
```

I can override compareTo function just once.
I know that I can make override something like this:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>{
public int number1;
public int number2;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo other){
         if(number2 !=  // something)
             return Int.compare(number, other.number);
         else
             return Int.compare(number2, other.number2);
    }
}
```

In this case complicity of program is different. 
Can I make something like in C++ in Java?

Comment: No, Other than attempting to have similar code structure. you really can't translate C++ idoms to Java. Both languages have different ideologies. And You should know that Java's **generics** [is different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java) from C++'s **templates**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your Java `PriorityQueue`, use the constructor that takes a `Comparator`. This allows you to use whatever comparison logic you want, despite any `compareTo` method that may already be defined for the class.