# Generic constraint as type list? Or compile-time duck typing?

Tags: kotlin

The following minimal example shows my problem quite well, I hope:

```
data class OneThing(val x: Int, val y: Int, val foo: String)
data class ASimilarThing(val x: Int, val y: Int, val bar: String)

fun <THING> process(thing: THING) {
    println(thing.x)
    println(thing.y)
}

fun main() {
    val oneThing = OneThing(1, 2, "hi")
    val aSimilarThing = ASimilarThing(3, 4, "ho")
    process(oneThing)
    process(aSimilarThing)
}
```

The two classes `OneThing` and `ASimilarThing` come from a library, so I can not change them. But semantically they are very similar, and I'd like to avoid implementing my logic two times, so I'd like to have it in a generic `process` function.

**However the above does not compile.** ([In C++ it is possible.](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/4b732b4226b62d4eff9a3ea89b13cba4))

Is there a way to make `process` work? Ideally I'm looking for something like

```
fun <THING: [OneThing, ASimilarThing]> process(thing: THING) { ... }
```

But such a syntax does not exist.

Any other ideas? :)

Comment: Templates in C++ are not the same thing and don't work the same way as generics in Kotlin or Java.

Comment: @TimCastelijns With `where` with multiple constraints does the opposite of what I like to achieve. It "and" combines the single constraints. But I'd like to "or" combine them. :)

Comment: @Jesper Thanks, I know. The C++ example was just for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Kotlin* like *Java* is a statically typed, object oriented language. Therefore you'd have to provide an common supertype declaring the properties `x` and `y`.

As this is not the case you cannot achieve duck typing as you like. `THING` has a supertype of `Any?` and therefore `x` and `y` are not accessible.

You could work around your issue by using a wrapper or delegate:

```
sealed class Thing {
    abstract val x: Int
    abstract val y: Int
}
class ASimilar(
    delegate: orig.OneThing
): Thing() {
    override val x get() = delegate.x
    override val y get() = delegate.y
}
class ASimilarThing(
    delegate: orig.ASimilarThing
): Thing() {
    override val x get() = delegate.x
    override val y get() = delegate.y
}


fun process(thing: Thing) {
    println(thing.x)
    println(thing.y)
}
```

Comment: C++ is also statically typed and object oriented. ;) Thanks, your idea works, but again introduces too much duplication for my taste.

Comment: True. I wanted to go into that direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java, but might have missed the actually relevant property which makes the difference. In _Java_ and therefore _Kotlin_ it's just not possible - sadly.