# Improving Comparable<T> compareTo performance

Tags: java, performance, comparable, virtual-functions

I profiled my code and found out that my class, which implements `Comparable<T>`, spends 8x more cpu time in

```
compareTo(Object)
```

than in

```
compareTo(T)
```

I assume that the slowdown is because of virtual table lookup for this method.

**Is there a way to force static invocation of the function?** (like in non virtual C++ methods)

I still want to use the `Comparable<T>` interface since I use `TreeSet` with this object and I'd like not to rewrite this code.

EDIT: No, I didn't implement the *compareTo(Object)* - this was automatically generated and reported by the profiler

Comment: And the two compareTo's are exactly the same other than casting?

Comment: There will typically be a bridging method where compareTo(Object) calls compareTo(ThisConcreteType). Presumably the latter does almost nothing. -server might help inline things.

Comment: Done a back-of-an-envelope performance calculation?

Comment: The bridging method should be automatically generated by the compiler, as implementing Comparable<T> only requires you to write the compareTo(T) method.

Comment: Yes, but the bridging method still gets executed and appears in the profiler.

Comment: How you found a way to improve performance?
I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

the reason you are seeing `compareTo(Object)` is because of [Type Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  it just means that at runtime the type information is no longer needed for comparing the values.
most likely the reason for your slowdown is 
1) very, very big TreeSet with lots of elements
2)  - more likely - your compareTo method does something expensive. because it is called very often (n*ln(n) times typically ), it should be implemented efficiently

Comment: I do use a large TreeSet intentionally, and that's why I tried to make it as fast as possible - it has one dereferencing and two comparisons only.

Comment: use treeSet only when neccesary. if you need your set sorted only at certain times, consiser using HashSet and sort it when you need it sorted, not all the time.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't force static invocation in this case.

An instance method can be invoked "non-virtually" by the `invokespecial` instruction. This instruction is used when the target is known at compile time, like a constructor or a private method. In other cases—even when the target method is `final`—the `invokevirtual` or `invokeinterface` instructions are used.

Comment: Point of pedantry: Or more likely in this case, invokeinterface, as Comparable is an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Since java does [not preserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373363/why-arent-java-generic-type-parameters-reified-at-runtime) generic types at runtime, ideally both of them should behave the same. Probably, there is something else which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that the slowdown is because
>   of virtual table lookup for this
>   method.

You shouldn't have to guess if this is true.
Just pause it a few times, and you will catch it in the act.
Display the call stack in its entirety, including calls into library routines.

My guess (which could be wrong) is that it's going through nine-yards of OLE-style invocation hoo-haw.