# What is truly wrong with Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some claim that Java's implementation of generics is bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520527/why-do-some-claim-that-javas-implementation-of-generics-is-bad)

What's really so wrong with Java's generics?  Or perhaps another way, what's so much better about other languages' implementations of similar concepts?

I don't mean to spark any wars, but I haven't programmed in Java since 1.4 (i.e. before generics).  In other questions (e.g. question 282329, [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329)), people talk about "oddities" without elaborating.

Anybody care to elaborate?

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520527/why-do-some-claim-that-javas-implementation-of-generics-is-bad, I don't know what a duplicate is.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520527/why-do-some-claim-that-javas-implementation-of-generics-is-bad