# How does Java type erasure work when the type parameter is used for casting?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I know generally unbound type parameters are substituted with `Object` in compile time. But how does this piece of code work?

```
<T> void call(List<T> list, Object o) {
    fun((T) o);
}
```

Will it be compiled to

```
void call(List list, Object o) {
    fun((Object) o);
}
```

Which seems like a wrong case because `o` should be cast to the same type as the elements in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because type information is available in java only in runtime, hence it won't compile to anything more specific than `Object`. Other case would be, if type parameter `T` was bound, for example:

```
 <T extends Number> void call(List<T> list, Object o) {
     fun((T) o);
 }
```

Then the compiler doesn't know the exact type at compile time, but it does know it's a subtype of `Number`, so if method `fun` consumed `Number` as parameter, it would compile as opposed to the first example.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520527/why-do-some-claim-that-javas-implementation-of-generics-is-bad).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! But I don't fully understand the answer. First of all, will the code compile to `fun((Number) o)` or just `fun(o)` in your example? Secondly, I don't get the point of the statement on `fun` consuming `Number`, I got lost because I think `fun` only consumes one parameter, so where is the second parameter?

Comment: 1. Yes, that would be the result - `fun((Number) o)`. 2. Sorry, I meant just parameter, corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because of type erasure even if your type is `A`, it will be treated as `Object` in your example as you guessed. which means if you passed your second elem other than `A`, it will actually be casted to `Object`.

Example,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TypeErasure {

    static <A> void call(List<A> list, Object elem) {
        A o1 = (A) elem;
        System.out.println(o1);
    }

    static void callV2(List list, Object elem) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }

    //bounded type
    static <A extends Number> void callV3(List<A> list, Object elem) {
        A o1 = (A) elem;
        System.out.println(o1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        call(new ArrayList<Integer>(), "trying to cast string to Integer");
        callV2(new ArrayList<Integer>(), "trying to cast string to Integer");

        //will be casted to Number
        callV3(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 1);
        callV3(new ArrayList<Double>(), 1.5);
        callV3(new ArrayList<Long>(), 1L);

        // following will fail at runtime with ClassCastException
        /* Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
           class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number 
          (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in 
           module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        */
        callV3(new ArrayList<Integer>(), "trying to cast string to Integer");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! So in `callV3`, `A o1 = (A) elem` will be compiled to `Number o1 = (Number) elem`?

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be compiled to

No, no cast will be inserted if the bound is `Object`, because a cast to `Object` always succeeds.

If the type variable were bounded, e.g. `T extends Number`, then a `checkcast` instruction would be inserted to ensure that `o` is a `Number`, equivalent to `(Number) o`.

You may notice that the compiler generates a unchecked warning on that line. An unchecked warning means that the compiler is unable to insert a bytecode to ensure that `o` is an instance of `T`, specifically.

---

It's also worth pointing out that the type variable is redundant. You can use the following, and it will be equivalent:

```
void call(List<?> list, Object o) {
    fun(o);
}
```

The cast is unnecessary, since `fun` must be able to accept any `Object` anyway.