# Java Generics for C# Gurus

Tags: c#, java, generics, reference

Are there any good quick reference guides out there (preferably online) for Java Generics from the perspective of someone with complete understanding of C# Generics? I find that the syntax is so similar that I expect it to just work and then I run into unfamiliar Java syntax like this:

```
Class<?> foo;
```

which I thought was similar to the C#:

```
Type<T> foo;
```

but that doesn't really seem to make sense in the context that I'm seeing it. Especially since there is a lack of context for `T` like there would be in C#.

Comment: Thanks all who answered. Each of the 3 answers had a part of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/2007/Aug-31.html has a fairly good post on the topic.

There is a post here as well with some further discussion that may be helpful
[C# vs Java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355060/c-vs-java-generics)

Comment: That was a helpful link. I think this answer satisfies the overall question most closely.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is called unbound wildcards.
Unfortunately C# doesn't support them. Also C# 2.0-3.5 has no implementation of covariant and contravariant generics. Latter are introduced C# 4.0.
Instead of `Class<?> foo;` you can write `Class<object> foo;` in C#.
Basically ? was introduced in Java generics for backward compatibility with older versions.

Short answer is no, you don't have direct representation of ? in C#, I'd suggest you to replace it with object type, or make it template converting the whole class to template class.

Comment: I appreciate the detail about the specific example. In C# though, `Class` is called `Type` and it isn't generic so you can't add a generic parameter to it.  So if I'm understanding correctly, the closest C# match for `Class<?>` would be `Type`.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial from sun http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Comment: Good link to have as definitive reference. Thanks.