# Differences between Generics in C#/.NET and in Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# vs Java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355060/c-vs-java-generics)

What is the differences between implementation of generics in C#/.NET and in Java?

What is the differences between support of generics by theirs runtime/vm?

Comment: @Darin, @ColinD, @Oded, @Ian Henry, @Pablo: Sorry, `Related` didn't listed that question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't like to re-hash content already available...so check out [Jonathan Pryor's comparison of Java and C# Generics](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/2007/Aug-31.html) on his blog.

The second half of the post is dedicated to the implementation of each on their respective VMs.

Answer (score 2):

Main difference is that generics are supported at the language and VM level in .NET, whereas in Java, they are only supported at the language level (JVM doesn't know anything about generics).

Comment: That's right... No runtime type information on generic types in java. Sad.