# C# Generics: If T is a return type, can it also be void? How can I combine these interfaces together?

Tags: c#, api, generics, api-design, nul

I have the following interface that returns the generic parameter of type T using a callback...

```
public interface IDoWork<T>
{
    T DoWork();
}
```

however I also have the following interface as well, but it won't invoke a callback since it returns void.

```
public interface IDoWork
{
    void DoWork();
}
```

Can I combine these two interfaces and use runtime logic to determine the difference?  How can I do that?

Comment: Too bad you're not in Java land, as you'd be totally capable of doing something like `IDoWork<Void> ...`. I'm sort of surprised that C# doesn't offer such a thing.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell, that's because .NET generics are built into the CLR, while in Java it's just a compiler trick (the JVM doesn't know anything about generics at runtime). While this is usually an advantage of .NET generics, it also means the rules are more strict...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Where can I learn more how .NET's approach is an advantage over Java?

Comment: @makerofthings7, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355060/c-sharp-vs-java-generics)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLevesque ; TL;DR version:  The benefits of C# generics over Java are preformance improvements, deep type safety verification and reflection

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, they can't be combined.

You can see this in the framework - that's why there is a separate [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) and [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) class, for example.

That being said, you can often share implementations in this type of scenario by using `IDoWork<object>` and passing `null` for values, etc.

Comment: I wonder if T== object, and object == null in the implementation then I can skip the callback in the host.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @makerofthings7 You ~could~ - but it may be inappropriate if null is an expected or valid value..

Comment: Personally as their behavour is different I'd want to give them slightly different names to express that difference.

Comment: @ShaunWilde I would, too - I'd have two separate interfaces in this type of scenario since they're really very different.

Answer (score 2):

return type is a part of method signature, so T DoWork() and void DoWork() are different, and void is not a type and it is not a `null`. It is an indication there is nothing in evaluation stack on return from method.

Comment: In c# return type is not part of [method signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)