# C# Generics: Constraining T where T : Object doesn't compile; Error: Constraint cannot be special class 'object'

Tags: c#, .net, generics, object, clr

When I constrain T with : Object like this:

```
public interface IDoWork<T> where T : Object
{
    T DoWork();
}
```

I get the error:

> Constraint cannot be special class 'object'

Does that mean there is an implied difference with the following that does compile?

```
public interface IDoWork<T> // where T : Object
{
    T DoWork();
}
```

Comment: All C# classes are subclasses of object. Such a constraint is a little bit strange :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I was trying to make T == Object == Void as in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10644495/328397

Comment: this constraint would be redundant, since this is the default...

Comment: See possible constraints here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Artem Chilin Correct. All classes are. But, not all types (eg: interfaces). However, an object at runtime has to be an instance of a type that inherits from System.Object.

Comment: FWIW, Its also possible that someone doing `where T : Object` is trying to say "its a reference type but not a value type".  @Douglas answer shows the solution for that:  `where T : class`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference between the two constraints, except for that one is disallowed for being useless to explicitly state.

The C# 4.0 language specification (10.1.5 Type parameter constraints) says two things about this:

> The type must not be object. Because all types derive from object,
> such a constraint would have no effect if it were permitted.
>
> ...
>
> If T has no primary constraints or type parameter constraints, its
> effective base class is object.

In your comment, you said that you were trying to make `T` be of type `Void`. `Void` is a special type that indicates that there is no return type and cannot be used in place of `T`, which requires an appropriate concrete type. You will have to create a void version of your method and a `T` version if you want both.

Comment: What about structs, though? I tried this to disallow a ton of non-nullable things like 'int'.

Answer (score 60):

If you want to constrain a generic type to be a reference type, use `: class`.

```
public interface IDoWork<T> where T : class
{
    T DoWork();
}
```

This will forbid the generic type from being a value type, such as `int` or a struct.

Comment: I don't know what the interface is used for, but it seems strange to forbid value types... a task that returns an int or a bool is fairly common.

Comment: Your point is valid, but I don’t know what the intention of the OP is either. I assumed that `: Object` meant that they were trying to constrain to reference types.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: There are many situations where generic code will work with any reference type, but cannot work with any generic value types; a simple example would be any code that either uses `Interlocked.CompareExchange` or other uses generic classes that do so.  A `struct` constraint isn't quite so useful, though it does allow a type to be used as a `Nullable<T>`.  Also, there are situations where value types which implements an interface "properly" may work, but classes that implement the interface cannot possibly work.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: A common reason to restrict to reference type:  Desire to return `null` when a valid object cannot be returned. `null` is only meaningful/valid for reference types.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I was trying object instead of class myself too. My case was:     interface IItemFactory<Item> where Item: class { Item Create(Item copyFrom = null); } - trying to use a default null value there and it was complaining without the constraint. Also tried Item? and Nullable<Item> in the method to no avail (was showing different errors). Guess those would work if I has a constraint to a struct or something. Wonder how you can make it to accept a null default parameter for any time (both value and reference types)

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: Specifying a parameter type of `T?` would be allowed if you provide a generic constraint of `where T : struct`. This unfortunately means that you cannot directly share the implementation between classes and nullable structs, but you could do so indirectly (through private classes or methods).

Comment: the question is though, if the compiler should be more clever there and allow Item Create(Item? copyFrom = null) for any type, both objects and non-object types, since I write Item? - it doesn't seem to allow that either though

Comment: `T?` is just syntactic sugar for [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a struct that wraps other value types: `public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct`. It cannot be used for reference types, which are intrinsically nullable in .NET. I agree; the language could have been designed to support common implementations for the two, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As per C# 4.0 Language Specification (Coded : [10.1.5] Type parameter constraints) tells two things:

> 1] The type must not be object. Because all types derive from object,
> such a constraint would have no effect if it were permitted.
>
> 2] If T has no primary constraints or type parameter constraints, its effective
> base class is object.

When you define a generic class, you can apply restrictions to the kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it instantiates your class. If client code tries to instantiate your class by using a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result is a compile-time error. These restrictions are called constraints. Constraints are specified by using the where contextual keyword.
**If you want to constrain a generic type to be a reference type, use : class.**

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56b2hk61.aspx)

Constraint cannot be special class 'identifier'. The following types may not be used as constraints:

- System.Object
- System.Array
- System.Delegate
- System.Enum
- System.ValueType.

Comment: This answer would be useful if it explained *why* these are not meaningful as constraints, and what to do instead. I don't have an answer for such questions, but here is another link with more discussion of constraints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've elaborated my answer a bit.