# Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Object'

Tags: c#-2.0

My function requires you pass it a string and a Type as T. Based on T i want to parse the string val as that type, but I get the error from the title of this question. Anyone that has any insight or other ways of accomplishing this function, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
T Parse<T>(string val) where T : System.Object
    {
        TypeCode code = Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T));
        switch (code)
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                return System.Boolean.Parse(val);
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                return Int32.Parse(val);
                break;
            case TypeCode.Double:
                return Double.Parse(val);
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                return (string)val;
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing there is abusing generics. If you are going to check for a type, why use generics at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Generics: Constraining T where T : Object doesn't compile; Error: Constraint cannot be special class 'object'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644703/c-sharp-generics-constraining-t-where-t-object-doesnt-compile-error-constr)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just remove `where T : System.Object`.

By stating:

```
where T : System.Object
```

you're saying that the types `T` usable in your method `Parse` must inherit from object.
But, since every object in C# inherits from `System.Object` you don't need that constraint (and probably that's one of the reasons why the compiler does not allow that).

Also, since you're returning `null`, you should constraint the type `T` to be a reference type, so:

```
where T: class
```

But in this way you can't return a boolean, integer or whatever value type.

However, your code basically mimics the functionality of `Convert.ChangeType`, the only difference is that you're using generics to return the correct type instead of object, but is basically equal to this:

```
T Parse<T>(string val)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val,typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Searched for something else but found this response that solved my problem.