# How were Unity developers able to constrain a generic type parameter on being derived from Object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, constraints

How were Unity developers able to constrain a generic type parameter on being derived from Object?

While looking for an answer to the question I come over [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644703/c-sharp-generics-constraining-t-where-t-object-doesnt-compile-error-constr). There is the answer which tells the following:

> There is no difference between the two constraints, except for that one is disallowed for being useless to explicitly state.

Proving that it should be impossible to constrain on Object. While in Unity we can see the following method:

```
public static T Instantiate<T>(T original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) where T : Object;
```

[image]

Does it happen because Unity is using Mono, but not CLR?

Comment: Unity has it's own [object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) definition, which differs from System.Object, which is constrained.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your question or don't understand it, but are you aware that the Unity Object class is not the same as the one from the System namespace: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `Object` constraint isn't `System.Object`, it's `UnityEngine.Object`, the class you're look at.

For example...

```
//public class Object { }

public class MyClass<T> where T : Object { }
```

Fails to compile, with error:

> CS0702 Constraint cannot be special class 'object'

…but will succeed if you uncomment the first line.

Comment: Oh. Lol, I missed such an easy to notice point. Thank you for helping me out. :)

Comment: Lol... I dare to speculate that there have been more than one *Doh!* from members of the Unity dev team as a result of this naming decision.

Comment: @qqqqqqq You are not the first one confused by this

Comment: @qqqqqqq it was chosen because it is mainly the base class of Game**Object** and Scriptable**Object** well and then also all components and other assets ^^ .. though they could've at least called it `UnityObject` in my opinion ^^

Comment: I've been thinking about it, I would have named it Unit.