# Using Generic Interface method only

Tags: c#

When i try to implement the following code

```
public interface IJob
{
    TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }
    int Priority { get; set; }
    bool Repeat { get; set; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    void Trigger();
}

public interface IJob<out T> : IJob
{
    new T Trigger();
}
```

like this

```
public class EmployeeJob : IJob<bool>
{
    bool IJob<bool>.Trigger()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public void Trigger()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

i have to implement both `Trigger` and `Trigger<bool>` methods while i only need `Trigger<bool>` in this case and vice versa for non generic type.

Comment: So what is your question? There's no way around it; since `IJob<T>` inherits `IJob`, you must implement all methods of both interfaces.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque my question is how could i somehow implement the method corresponding to the type of the class (if generic implement the generic Trigger only) if not then...

Comment: The way your code is currently structured, you have to implement both.  Generics are used for type variance but you are attempting to use `void` as a return type, which it is technically not.  See this here for a further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644495/c-sharp-generics-if-t-is-a-return-type-can-it-also-be-void-how-can-i-combine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the interfaces differently so that the non-generic interface doesn't expose the `void Trigger()` method:

```
public interface IJobBase
{
    TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }
    int Priority { get; set; }
    bool Repeat { get; set; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public interface IJob : IJobBase
{
    void Trigger();
}

public interface IJob<out T> : IJobBase
{
    T Trigger();
}
```

Comment: is there any other way because i have a list of IJob interface and now i couldn't use one list anymore ? could i ?

Comment: @DanielEugen You can have a list of `IJobBase` but you'll need to cast to use either `Trigger()`

Comment: so how to tell at run time whether it is generic or not and get it's type and cast upon that ?

Comment: @DanielEugen Reflection.  Or you can have `Trigger` call `Trigger<T>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement both of them because you implement both `IJob<T>` and `IJob`.  Using `new` does *not* mean you don't have to implement the base - it means you need to *explicitly* implement one of the methods or there would be a collision.  In concrete classes, `new` *hides* the base member, it does not *override* it.  For interfaces, it means "I want to add *another* method that has the same signature as the base method.  implementers still need to implement both, but now must implement all but one explicitly.

If `Trigger` is the only function that will have both generic and non-generic flavors then those could be in orthogonal interfaces:

```
public interface IJobBase
{
    TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }
    int Priority { get; set; }
    bool Repeat { get; set; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public interface IJob : IJobBase
{
    void Trigger();
}

public interface IJob<out T> : IJobBase
{
    T Trigger();
}
```

or just "link" the two methods:

```
bool IJob<bool>.Trigger()
{
    // do something and return a bool
}


public void Trigger()
{
    (IJob<bool>(this)).Trigger();  // ignore the return value
}
```