# why i can't create a Map of String and generic object

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to do something like this

```
  final Map<String, ? extends Object> params = new HashMap<String, ? extends Object>();
```

but java compiler complaining about that "cannot instantiate the type HashMap();

whats wong with it..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e/15252219#15252219

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`? extends Object` is a wildcard.  It stands for "some unknown type, and the only thing we know about it is it's a subtype of `Object`".   It's fine in the declaration but you can't instantiate it because it's not an actual type.  Try

```
final Map<String, ? extends Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Because you do not know what type the `?` is you can't assign anything to it.  Since `Object` is a supertype of everything, `params` can be assigned be assigned a reference to both `HashMap<String, Integer>` as well as `HashMap<String, String>`, among many other things.  A `String` is not an `Integer` nor is an `Integer` a `String`.  The compiler has no way of knowing which `params` may be, so it is not a valid operation to put anything in `params`.

If you want to be able to put `<String, String>` in `params` then declare it as such.  For example,

```
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("a", "blah");
```

For a good intro on the subject, take a look at the Java Language tutorial on generics, esp. [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) and the one after it.

Comment: but then what if i want to store

Comment: @Saurabh That will work fine, since the String class (like almost all classes) is a subclass of Object. This implementation works fine if you want to store an instance of absolutely any class in your HashMap. Some details on what you're actually trying to achieve would probably help us to determine whether or not this is the correct approach.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear why 
`final Map<String, Object> params = Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap();` doesn't work.  Throws `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to put `<String,String>`

Comment: Also, IntelliJ (in Java 14) suggests doing `Map<String, ?>` instead of `Map<String, ? extends Object>`...

Answer (score 0):

```
? extends Object
```

does not evaluate to any Type. so you can not mention like that. 
1. If you want AnyType extends Object, then why do'nt you simply pass Object.
as anyType that extends Object is also an Object. and by default every Java class Type extends Object.
2. If you want specifically TypeA extends TypeB, 
  then you can do like

```
Map<String, TypeB>
```