# Why is returning List<? extends T> read-only and returning List<? super T> write-only?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a difference between <? super E> and <? extends E>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e)

Some Java programmers on a team I'm on are writing functions that return objects of type `List<? extends T>` to make read-only lists and return objects of type `List<? super T>` to make write-only lists.

In Java, what makes `List<? extends T>` read-only and `List<? super T>` write-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read up on "producer extends, consumer super" (PECS) - I may need to do the same :)

Read only:

In case you would like to ensure that a method takes as a parameter a collection of items ( using generics) - when you use `List<? extends T>` - the list can contain any subtype of T but cannot add to the collection since it does not know at runtime the specific type of T that the List contains.

Write only:

For `List<? super T>`, the list can contain T regardless of the actual parameterized type (using super will allow that to happen).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `T` from a `List<? extends T>`, but the only thing you can put into it is a `null` literal. You can put a `T` into a `List<? super T>`, but the only thing you can get from it is an `Object` (which is then unsafe to cast down to `T`).

So, the restrictions make these pretty good, though imperfect, reminders of the intention. With a `List<? extends T>`, you can't put most things into it -- so it's kinda read-only. And with a `List<? super T>`, you can't get things out of it very usefully -- so it's kinda write-only.

Note that neither one of these is *actually* read- or write-only. I noted some of the ways you can get things into or out of them above, and with the "read-only" construct, you can still call `remove` functions, either on the object itself or on its iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The definition `List<? extends T>` means "a `List<X>` implementation, where `X` must be `T` or a subclass/implementation thereof. In other words, your only guarantee is that objects already stored in the list will fit in a variable of type `T`. However, since the list may have been declared for a class extending or implementing T, you have no guarantee that objects of type `T` itself will fit into the list.

Simple example: `List<String>` is a `List<? extends T>` if `T` is `Object`. You can safely draw `Object`-type objects from it, but you can obviously not put other `Object`-type objects in it, unless they are definitely strings.