# Aren't <U, T extends U> and <T, U super T> the same?

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-parameter

I have a confusion in following two method declarations:

```
    private <U, T extends U> T funWorks(T child, U parent) {
      // No compilation errors
    }

    private <T, U super T> T funNotWorks(T child, U parent) {
      // compilation errors    
    }
```

Shouldn't both of the above be valid? With the analogy of  **If U is parent of T , then T is child of U**. Then why does 2nd one gives compilation error?

EDIT::
I think , `T extends T` and `T super T` both are valid. right ?

Comment: I suspect `T extends U` means `T >= U` where `U super T` means `U < T`, but I could be wrong ...

Comment: You should take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e)

Comment: @DayS : Thats about ? - anything.  I understand that. But whats in case of T and U ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bounding generics with 'super' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Type parameters (your example) can only use extends ([JLS #4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)):

```
TypeParameter:
    TypeVariable TypeBoundopt

TypeBound:
    extends TypeVariable
    extends ClassOrInterfaceType AdditionalBoundListopt

AdditionalBoundList:
    AdditionalBound AdditionalBoundList
    AdditionalBound

AdditionalBound:
    & InterfaceType
```

- Wildcards can use either `extends` or `super` ([JLS #4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)):

```
TypeArguments:
    < TypeArgumentList >

TypeArgumentList: 
    TypeArgument
    TypeArgumentList , TypeArgument

TypeArgument:
    ReferenceType
    Wildcard

Wildcard:
    ? WildcardBoundsopt

WildcardBounds:
    extends ReferenceType
    super ReferenceType
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't bound a named generic with super. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword) stackoverflow posting.